# how to find out if a checkbox is checked in jQuery

Tags: jquery

is there a simple way to find out if a checkbox is checked in jquery.

something like .checked or ischecked

Comment: Duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/jquery-check-if-checkbox-is-checked

Comment: You're not new here (32 questions). Certainly you must be aware that you can search stackoverflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
el.is(':checked')
```

That's the jQuery way. At its core, though, it's just a bit more parsing to get down to `el[0].checked`, using the raw DOM property, so take whichever you prefer. The DOM method is probably better for actually testing an element, whereas `:checked` is better for selecting it in the first place.

Comment: `el[0].checked`, no reason to not use the DOM property when in an `if` statement, it's much faster :)