# jQuery if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, if-statement

I have a function below that I want to trigger only when a checkbox in the same `tr` is checked.

```js
$(".add_menu_item_table").live('click', function() {
  if ($('input.checkbox_check').attr(':checked')); {
    // I want this to trigger.
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="table-data">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_check"></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="add_menu_item_table" value="Add"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_check"></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="add_menu_item_table" value="Add"></td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('input.checkbox_check').checked` returns `true` if it's checked, `false` otherwise

Comment: @mmcrae, that's incorrect.  The jQuery object has no property `checked`. I think you meant `$('input.checkbox_check')[0].checked`

Comment: One of those "come on jquery" moments. They could litterally write `checked: function(){return this.is(:checked)}` and be done with it.

Answer (score 1301, accepted):

```
if ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')) {
```

Comment: Code confirmed by jQuery doc, "the cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to use the property: `if ( elem.checked )` or `if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) )` or `if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )` ". see http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: If we are going to be talking about performance then some of these comments should be added directly to the question asked by Clinton, and suggesting that the absolute fastest recommendation would be to add an ID

Comment: another possibility is simply `if ($('#my_input:checked))`

Answer (score 154):

for jQuery 1.6 or higher:

```
if ($('input.checkbox_check').prop('checked')) {
    //blah blah
}
```

> the cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked
>   is to use the property https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Note that "The .prop() method gets the property value for only the first element in the matched set." see http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 88):

- To verify if it is checked

  ```
  $('#checkboxId').is(':checked')
  ```
- To check

  ```
  $("#checkboxId").prop('checked', true)
  ```
- To uncheck

  ```
  $("#checkboxId").prop('checked', false)
  ```

Answer (score 38):

If none of the above solutions work for any reason, like my case, try this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
      $('[name="my_checkbox"]').change(function()
      {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           // Do something...
           alert('You can rock now...');
        };
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 16):

If **checked**:

```
$( "SELECTOR" ).attr( "checked" )  // Returns ‘true’ if present on the element, returns undefined if not present
$( "SELECTOR" ).prop( "checked" ) // Returns true if checked, false if unchecked.
$( "SELECTOR" ).is( ":checked" ) // Returns true if checked, false if unchecked.
```

Get the **checked** val:

```
$( "SELECTOR:checked" ).val()
```

Get the **checked** val numbers:

```
$( "SELECTOR:checked" ).length
```

Check or uncheck **checkbox**

```
$( "SELECTOR" ).prop( "disabled", false );
$( "SELECTOR" ).prop( "checked", true );
```

Comment: `$( "SELECTOR:checked" ).val()` on `value="on"` gives you "on" if checked and "" if unchecked - useful!

Answer (score 10):

See main difference between **ATTR | PROP | IS** below:

[Source: http://api.jquery.com/attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)/

```js
$( "input" )
  .change(function() {
    var $input = $( this );
    $( "p" ).html( ".attr( 'checked' ): <b>" + $input.attr( "checked" ) + "</b><br>" +
      ".prop( 'checked' ): <b>" + $input.prop( "checked" ) + "</b><br>" +
      ".is( ':checked' ): <b>" + $input.is( ":checked" ) + "</b>" );
  })
  .change();
```

```css
p {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
  }
  b {
    color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>attr demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<label for="check1">Check me</label>
<p></p>
 

 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `.is(':checked')` method which returns **true** if an element is checked, otherwise it returns **false**.

### Example

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){
  isChecked = $(this).is(':checked')
  
  if(isChecked){ 
    $('html').css('background-color','green')
  }
  else{ 
    $('html').removeAttr('style')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox"> Try me </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

New to jQuery/Javascript and tried the above solutions.  Eventually, this is what worked for me to:

1. keep elements hidden upon loading page (because checkboxes = unchecked by default), and then
2. have elements show/hide based on whether the checkbox is checked or not.

It's probably a little ugly/redundant/extraneous syntax-wise, but it works for now!

---

Note:  this all goes in the following `<script>` tag, right before the `</body>` tag on your HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // 'solution code' goes here...
</script>
```

'solution code':

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

          // HIDE ELEMENTS UPON PAGE LOAD (CHECKBOX = UNCHECKED)
          if ($([id="show_box"]).is(':checked') == false)
                $("#hiddenDiv").hide();

          // SHOW/HIDE ELEMENTS VIA CHECKBOX STATUS
          $('[id="show_box"]').change(function()
          {
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                $("#hiddenDiv").fadeIn();
            else
                $("#hiddenDiv").fadeOut();
          });

    });
```

- **[id="show_box"]** (the checkbox, with id 'show_box')
- **#hiddenDiv** (the id of the element I want to hide/show)
- **this** (since it's nested, it ends up representing 'show_box')

And here is the HTML code on the page, which the 'solution code' is referring to:

```
<!-- CHECKBOX -->
<input type="checkbox" id="show_box" name="box" value="">

<!-- ELEMENT THAT SHOWS/HIDES -->
<div id="hiddenDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to check input and get confirm by check box ,use this script...

```js
 $(document).on("change", ".inputClass", function () {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
     confirm_message = $(this).data('confirm');
       var confirm_status = confirm(confirm_message);
                        if (confirm_status == true) {
                           //doing somethings...
                         }
                   }});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> check action </lable>
<input class="inputClass" type="checkbox" data-confirm="are u sure to do ...?" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to know this property to automatically check/uncheck "sub-checkboxes" and this is working :

```
jQuery('.checkbox-parent').click(function(){
    jQuery('.checkbox-child').prop(
        'checked', 
        jQuery('.checkbox-parent').prop('checked')
    ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following can be done in both JavaScript and jQuery which is pretty simple.

```
var getVal=$('#isAgeSelected').is(":checked"); // jQuery

var getVal=document.getElementById("isAgeSelected").checked //JavaScript

if (getVal==true) {
// do something
} else {
// do something
}
```