# Javascript validation code to make sure that at least one checkbox is marked

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox

How would I add javascript validation to make sure that at least one of the items is checked?

Select from courses below:

```
        <ul id="class_prices">
             <li>

                <input onclick="update()" name="lbsm" id="lsbm" type="checkbox" value="lbsm">
                <label>Law &amp; Business Study Material ($59.00)</label>
            </li>

            <li>

                <input onclick="update()" name="tsm" id="tsm" type="checkbox" value="tsm">
                <label>Trade Study Material ($59.00)</label>
            </li>
            <li>

                <input onclick="update()" name="lbepc" id="lbepc" type="checkbox" value="lbepc">
                <label>Law &amp; Business Exam Preperation Class ($50.00)</label>
            </li>
            <li>

                <input onclick="update()" name="tepc" id="tepc" type="checkbox" value="tepc">
                <label>Trade Exam Preperation Class ($50.00)</label>
            </li>

        </ul>

        </td>

            <td><h2>$<span id="coursetotal"></span></h2></td>
                </tr>
```

Here is javascript code that I have, which does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function valthisform() {
    var chkd = document.form1.lsbm.checked || document.form1.tsm.checked||  document.form1.lbepc.checked|| document.form1.tepc.checked

    if (chkd == true) { } else { alert ("please check a checkbox") }
  }
</script>
```

I will appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Your code was pretty messy... and it was just a few lines! Use proper indentation so that is easier to read. Never use something like `chkd == true`. If you really need to test if something is true, use `if( chkd )`. In your case, chkd is either `undefined` or `"checked"`. `if( chkd == true )` will return false in either case. Use either `if( chkd == undefined )` or `if( !chkd )` and remove the empty code block altogether.

Comment: I tried that and it does not work.  This is the page that I'm working on. https://www.contractorsintelligence.com/secured_payment/postinglist-promotional-offer-59.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960208/jquery-if-checkbox-is-checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your javascript and it seems to be working as you expected. There is one problem with the script itself, and that is that it doesn't return a value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function valthisform() {
    var chkd = document.form1.lsbm.checked || document.form1.tsm.checked||  document.form1.lbepc.checked|| document.form1.tepc.checked

    if (chkd) {
      return true; //Submit the form
    } else {
      alert ("please check a checkbox");
      return false; //Prevent it from being submitted
    }
  }
</script>
```

LiveValidationForm has a submit handler attached to the form too and that handler might interfere with your handler and/or prevent the form from being submitted.

---

Fun fact: You have `document.form1.lsbm.checked` properly misspelled in your javascript, as the element in your document has a properly misspelled id of `lsbm` instead of `lbsm` too.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried your code and it still does not work.  Is there anyway that I can fix it and have a Live Validation?

Comment: I am not familiar with LiveValidationForm. Can't you somehow put this in LiveValidationForm?

Comment: Thanks!  The code only worked after I fixed the PHP side.  I used if function in php.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the checkboxes inside the UL, and if any of them are checked, set the `chkd` variable to true :

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('class_prices').getElementsByTagName('input'),
    chkd = false;

for (var i=inputs.length; i--;) {
    if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox' && inputs[i].checked) chkd = true;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YBqL4/)

Comment: Just wondering if you know of any reason to use `.type.toLowerCase()`. I've never seen a case where, even if the attribute is in caps, the property isn't converted to lowercase. Then again, I don't do this check often/ever, and haven't tested in many/all browsers

Comment: @Ian - Uhm, well, can't say that I've ever seen the type in uppercase either, I just convert stuff to make sure, as I always tend to f**k up when comparing tagNames, and they return in uppercase !

Comment: Haha yeah, I definitely know to use this for `tagName`, I was just wondering specifically about `.type`. No big deal, just wondering :)

Comment: I'm new to javascript.  I tried to set these variable to true, but it still does not work.  Should I post this code into Javascript that I have above.  also you are mentioning "input" and "checkbox", should I replace those with the actual variable name of the check box?  Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="id1" style="margin-right: 10px;" name="class" checked> ABC</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="id2" style="margin-right: 10px;" name="class" checked>XYZ</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="id3" style="margin-right: 10px;"name="class" checked> LMN</label></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $('input[type="checkbox"][name="class"]').on('change', function () {
        var getArrVal = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="class"]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).toArray();
        if (getArrVal.length) {
        //execute the code
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
        alert("Select at least one column");
        return false;
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you've done here? That helps the user understand why this is an answer.

Comment: by default all check box checked,when i uncheck last checkbox give javascript alert message..