# How to validate checkboxes in particular div using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check whether checkbox in particular DIV is checked or not?

```
<div id="TeddyTab">
 <input type="checkbox" id="bla" />
 <input type="checkbox" id="bla1" />
 <input type="checkbox" id="bla2" />
</div>
```

JQuery?

```
 $(':checked').each(function() {
        if(this.checked === 'true')
            $(this).closest('div').next('div').find('textarea').prop('readonly',false);
    });
```

The above jquery checkes everything n page which i do not want. I want to check in above div only?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

use the below code to validate in particular div

```
 if($("#TeddyTab input:checked").size() > 0){
// do here what ever you wanna do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing boolean with string value as `this.checked` return boolean value. also you are only iterating over checked element which eliminates the need of using if condition

```
$(':checked').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').next('div').find('textarea').prop('readonly',false);
});
```

Comment: `if(this.checked)` This check is unnecessary since we are traversing over a checked check box elements/

Comment: Good catch... i didn't had loser look at loop. so there is no need to use if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Without much changes; Here is how it worked:

```
$('#TeddyTab :checkbox').each(function() {
 if(this.checked)
 $(this).closest('div').next('div').find('textarea').prop('readonly',false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Posible duplicated [jQuery if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960208/jquery-if-checkbox-is-checked)?
Anyway, this is how you should implement it:

```
$('#TeddyTab input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i,input){
      $(input).closest('div').next('div').find('textarea').prop('readonly',false);
```

or if you need the IF statement:

```
$('#TeddyTab input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i,input){
            if($(input).is(':checked')){ 
                $(input).closest('div').next('div').find('textarea').prop('readonly',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/K6Wvk/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#formid').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        'test[]': {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 2
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'test[]': {
            required: "You must check at least 1 box",
            maxlength: "Check no more than {0} boxes"
        }
    }
});
```

});