# Getting undefined output from jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting undefined output from my jQuery function below. I initially assigned empty string to my `product_type`, ***I want it to be empty when I don't choose anyone of them***, but still getting `undefined` output. Hopefully, I can have some hints here.

```js
$(function () {
    var internal_note = {};
    var customer_note = {};
    var product_type = "";
    var web_camera = "";
    var touch_screen = "";
    $( "#test" ).on("click" , 'button:not(:disabled)',function(event){
        if ($('input[name="product_type"]:checked')){
            product_type = $('input[name="product_type"]:checked').attr("value");
        };
        if($('input[name="web_camera"]:checked')){
           web_camera = $('input[name="web_camera"]:checked').attr("value");
        };
        if($('input[name="touch_screen"]:checked')){
           touch_screen = $('input[name="touch_screen"]:checked').attr("value");
        };
        $('#left_note_list input').each(function(){
            internal_note[this.value] = JSON.stringify($(this).val());
         });
        alert(product_type);
        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '/insert/',
        data: {
        'internal_note': JSON.stringify(internal_note),
        'product_type': JSON.stringify(product_type),
        'web_camera': JSON.stringify(web_camera),
        'touch_screen': JSON.stringify(touch_screen)
        },
        success: function (data) {
            swal(data,'You Click the Button','success');
            $("#test button:not(:disabled)").text('Done!').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
        error: function(data){
            swal(data.responseText,'You Click the Button', 'error');
        }

        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
     <h4 class="sub-header" id="product_type">Product Type</h4>
                        <form>
                            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="product_type" value="Laptop">Laptop</label></div>
                            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="product_type" value="Tower">Tower</label></div>
                            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="product_type" value="Minitower">Minitower</label></div>
                            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="product_type" value="Small Form Factor">Small Form Factor</label></div>
                        </form>
                  </div><!-- /.col-lg-4  Product Type-->
                  
                <div class="text-center" id="test">
                <button target="_blank"
                    class="btn btn-primary ">
                    Test
                </button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you recreate this issue in plunker or something equivalent?  It is hard to see what is going on from your code posted.

Comment: your question is unclear, when is it being undefined? After you click on `#test`?

Comment: @A.Lau I have updated my question. Thank you all

Comment: @TheMiddleMan I have uploaded the code to snippet

Comment: Please [don't put the tags in the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/194720).

Comment: did you try form.serialize()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the way you are checking to see is the checkbox is checked.  This if check `if ($('input[name="product_type"]:checked'))`.  This works, but you do not get a true or false answer back, so you are essentially checking truthy instead.  You can either check the length of `$('input[name="product_type"]:checked')` or you can do this instead

`$('input[name="product_type"]').is(":checked")`

Here is a good post on how to check whether or not a checkbox is checked

[jQuery if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960208/jquery-if-checkbox-is-checked)

```js
$(function () {
    var internal_note = {};
    var customer_note = {};
    var product_type = "";
    var web_camera = "";
    var touch_screen = "";
    $( "#test" ).on("click" , 'button:not(:disabled)',function(event){

        if ($('input[name="product_type"]').is(":checked")){
            product_type = $('input[name="product_type"]:checked').attr("value");
        }
        if($('input[name="web_camera"]:checked')){
           web_camera = $('input[name="web_camera"]:checked').attr("value");
        }
        if($('input[name="touch_screen"]:checked')){
           touch_screen = $('input[name="touch_screen"]:checked').attr("value");
        }
        $('#left_note_list input').each(function(){
            internal_note[this.value] = JSON.stringify($(this).val());
         });
        alert(product_type);
        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '/insert/',
        data: {
        'internal_note': JSON.stringify(internal_note),
        'product_type': JSON.stringify(product_type),
        'web_camera': JSON.stringify(web_camera),
        'touch_screen': JSON.stringify(touch_screen)
        },
        success: function (data) {
            swal(data,'You Click the Button','success');
            $("#test button:not(:disabled)").text('Done!').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },
        error: function(data){
            swal(data.responseText,'You Click the Button', 'error');
        }

        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4 class="sub-header" id="product_type">Product Type</h4>
                        <form>
                            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="product_type" value="Laptop">Laptop</label></div>
                            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="product_type" value="Tower">Tower</label></div>
                            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="product_type" value="Minitower">Minitower</label></div>
                            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="product_type" value="Small Form Factor">Small Form Factor</label></div>
                        </form>
                  </div><!-- /.col-lg-4  Product Type-->
                  
                <div class="text-center" id="test">
                <button target="_blank"
                    class="btn btn-primary ">
                    Test
                </button>
                </div>
```

Comment: @weijielin Happy coding :D

Answer (score 1):

It's because your conditional check is never returning false, so it's always assigning the value of product_type, even when nothing is selected.  Instead of the check you have, use this:

```
if ($('input[name="product_type"]:checked').length>0){ ... }
```

That'll correctly check to ensure you have a checked product type.