# how to enable button only after select box and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a small form where I have two input boxes, 1 select box and 1 checkbox and submit button.

I want the submit to be enabled when all fields are filled. Til now I am able to enable submit button after both input box value filled but I am not able to enable for select box and checkbox.

```js
var Seatname;
var Seatadmissionyr;
var Seatlevelselectval;
var SeatProgramLevel;
//var SeatAvailableFaculties;
$('#SaveNxt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('#contentHoldEdu input').change(function() {
  name = $('#Name').val()
  admissionyr = $('#AdmissionYear').val()
  SeatProgramLevel = $('#courseSelect option:selected').text();
  //SeatAvailableFaculties = $('.eduSelectedCheck').val()

  if ((name.length > 0) && (admissionyr.length > 0) && (course.length > 0)) {
    $('#Save').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {

    $('#Save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" id="contentHoldEdu" method="post">
  <div class="setup-content form-horizontal form-bordered" id="step-1">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter the name  <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="Name" type="text" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Admission Year <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="AdmissionYear" type="text" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="4" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select course <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <select id="courseSelect" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select" tabindex="1">
<option value="0" disabled selected default>--Select--</option>
                    <option value="B.tech">B.tech</option>
                    <option value="mba">Mba</option>
                   </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select all applicable faculties <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="portlet light portlet-fit box grey ">
          <div class="portlet-body">
            <table class="eduleveles table table-bordered table-hover">
              <thead>
                <th>confirm</th>
                <th> AC Room</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" /></td>
                  <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="Save" type="button">submit</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: course is not defined - how about `$('#courseSelect')[0].selectedIndex>0` and `$("[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")`

Comment: @mplungjan could you please help me with some working fiddle with my current jquery code?

Comment: Many other problems with your code
1. Both the input (name and AdmissionYear) have same 'name' attribute. Correct that otherwise form will not save values
2. Is there any specific reason why you have put in a table for alignment, instead of a div?
3. Assign an id or class to the checkbox field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wpuld say excecute the function onkeyup for input text box. Otherwise if the user fills in the input  textbox last he would not be able to directly click on the submit button. check out my code below

```js
var Seatname;
var Seatadmissionyr;
var Seatlevelselectval;
var SeatProgramLevel;
//var SeatAvailableFaculties;
$('#SaveNxt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

function changeDetected(){
  name = $('#Name').val()
  admissionyr = $('#AdmissionYear').val()
  SeatProgramLevel = $('#courseSelect').val();

  if ((name.length > 0) && (admissionyr.length > 0) && (SeatProgramLevel.length > 0) && ($('#confirmRoom').attr('checked') != undefined) && ($('#confirmRoom2').attr('checked') != undefined) && ($('#confirmRoom3').attr('checked') != undefined)) {
    $('#Save').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {

    $('#Save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>


<form role="form" id="contentHoldEdu" method="post">
  <div class="setup-content form-horizontal form-bordered" id="step-1">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter the name  <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="Name" type="text" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control" onkeyup="changeDetected()"/>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Admission Year <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="AdmissionYear" type="text" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="4" onkeyup="changeDetected()" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select course <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <select id="courseSelect" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select" tabindex="1" onchange="changeDetected()">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="B.tech">B.tech</option>
                    <option value="mba">Mba</option>
                   </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select all applicable faculties <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="portlet light portlet-fit box grey ">
          <div class="portlet-body">
            <table class="eduleveles table table-bordered table-hover">
              <thead>
                <th>confirm</th>
                <th> AC Room</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="confirmRoom" onchange="changeDetected()"/></td>
                  <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="confirmRoom2" onchange="changeDetected()"/></td>
                  <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="confirmRoom3" onchange="changeDetected()"/></td>
                  <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="Save" type="button" disabled="disabled">submit</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks , but i have one doubt what if we have more than two checkbox ?

Comment: you add onchange="changeDetected()" on each of them. and you'll have to check if they have been checked inside the changeDetected function.

Comment: if you dont want to keep checking, you could put all the input elements in a form tag and put the required atrribute in the input tags. This way you dont need to keep checking your changeDetected() function. The form wont allow you to move foward unless all inputs have been filled. Let me know if you want a code snippet for that.

Comment: hey @IhavCoder i dont want to use Required attr in input tags , i want to achieve it by jquery only because later i will convert my form into dynamic so all checkbox , options in select will come from backend. it would be great if you help me by jquery only (Fiddle with multiple checkbox)

Comment: i edited the above the code. check it out.... (modify the html according to your needs )

Comment: i rechecked its working. Why do you say its not working?

Comment: sorry! it was chrome browser issue.

Comment: if any of the answers helped you, you could upvote them :)

Answer (score 0):

To check if a checkox is checked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7960219/978649

And to check if `select` has the value that you expect just use like a common input text:

```
if($('#courseSelect').val() == '1') { ... }
// or
if($('#courseSelect').val() != '0') { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```js
var Seatname;
var Seatadmissionyr;
var Seatlevelselectval;
var SeatProgramLevel;
//var SeatAvailableFaculties;
$('#SaveNxt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('#contentHoldEdu input').change(function() {
  name = $('#Name').val()
  admissionyr = $('#AdmissionYear').val()
  SeatProgramLevel = $('#courseSelect option:selected').text();
  checkCtrl =  $("#thisCheck").is(':checked');

  if ((name.length > 0) && (admissionyr.length > 0) && checkCtrl == true && SeatProgramLevel != '--Select--' ) {
    alert('enable' + SeatProgramLevel + checkCtrl );
    $('#Save').prop('disabled','');
  } else {
     alert('disable' +  SeatProgramLevel + checkCtrl );
    $('#Save').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" id="contentHoldEdu" method="post">
  <div class="setup-content form-horizontal form-bordered" id="step-1">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter the name  <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="Name" type="text" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Admission Year <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="AdmissionYear" type="text" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="4" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select course <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <select id="courseSelect" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select" tabindex="1">
<option value="0" disabled selected default>--Select--</option>
                    <option value="B.tech">B.tech</option>
                    <option value="mba">Mba</option>
                   </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select all applicable faculties <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="portlet light portlet-fit box grey ">
          <div class="portlet-body">
            <table class="eduleveles table table-bordered table-hover">
              <thead>
                <th>confirm</th>
                <th> AC Room</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input id="thisCheck" type="checkbox" /></td>
                  <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="Save" type="button">submit</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: button is clickable

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the design pattern "State Machine" to handle situations, such this one. Here is you can checkout a simple example of that pattern: http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/state-design-pattern

> The State pattern provides state-specific logic to a limited set of objects in which each object represents a particular state.

Comment: Please do not post link only answers. It is not clear why your answer is relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with no HTML modification and in only one function:

```
function isReady() {
  contentReady = 0;
  $('#contentHoldEdu input, #contentHoldEdu select').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() && !($(this).val() == "on" && !$(this).is(":checked"))) {
      contentReady++;
    }
  });
  $("#Save").attr("disabled", contentReady != 4)
}
```

```js
var Seatname;
var Seatadmissionyr;
var Seatlevelselectval;
var SeatProgramLevel;
//var SeatAvailableFaculties;
$('#Save').attr('disabled', true);

$('#contentHoldEdu input, #contentHoldEdu select').on('input',isReady)

function isReady() {
  contentReady = 0;
  $('#contentHoldEdu input, #contentHoldEdu select').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() && !($(this).val() == "on" && !$(this).is(":checked"))) {
      contentReady++;
    }
  });
  console.log(contentReady);
  $("#Save").attr("disabled", contentReady != 4)
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" id="contentHoldEdu" method="post">
  <div class="setup-content form-horizontal form-bordered" id="step-1">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter the name  <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="Name" type="text" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Admission Year <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="AdmissionYear" type="text" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="4" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select course <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <select id="courseSelect" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select" tabindex="1">
<option value="" disabled selected default>--Select--</option>
                    <option value="B.tech">B.tech</option>
                    <option value="mba">Mba</option>
                   </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select all applicable faculties <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="portlet light portlet-fit box grey ">
          <div class="portlet-body">
            <table class="eduleveles table table-bordered table-hover">
              <thead>
                <th>confirm</th>
                <th> AC Room</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" /></td>
                  <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="Save" type="button">submit</button>
    </div>
```