# jQuery - Seeing if a "checbox" is checked on entry

Tags: jquery, each

I'm having trouble understanding why my second code here doesn't work (Ruhetag 2 which has just been edited). As a test to see if my targeting was ok I wrote Ruhetag1, which works find when clicking my checboxes, but I then wrote Ruhetag2 to also have the same function but in addition check to see which checkboxes were already checked on entry. Ruhetag1 works fine, Ruhetag2 isn't reacting at all - it's not giving me an error message either. Can you help me see where this is fallong down. Many thanks.

Ruhetag1

```
$(".quiet").click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().find(".optimes input[type=text]").val('');
    $(this).parent().find(".optimes").toggle(); 
});
```

Ruhetag2

```
$(function(){   
    $(".quiet").each(function(){
        quiet(this);
    });
    $(".quiet").click(function() {
        quiet(this);
    });
});
function quiet() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().find(".optimes input[type=text]").val('');
        $(this).parent().find(".optimes").hide();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find(".optimes").show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960208/jquery-if-checkbox-is-checked)

Comment: I'd already looked at the similar post but I'm not convinced it's the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Eddie, I tried but couldn't seem to get it right myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element isn't being passed to the function `quiet()`, so `$(this)` does not exist within the function. Try the below?:

```
$(function(){   
  $(".quiet").each(function(){
    quiet($(this));
  });
  $(".quiet").click(function() {
    quiet($(this));
  });
});

function quiet(elem) {
   var checkbox = elem;
       if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
          checkbox.parent().find(".optimes input[type=text]").val('');
          checkbox.parent().find(".optimes").hide();
      } else {
          checkbox.parent().find(".optimes").show();
      }
}
```

Comment: Olli - you're the best - that works perfectly - many thanks :-)