# Why does "this.checked" work but "$("#acept").checked" doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input like

```
   <input  type="checkbox" name="acept" id="acept">
```

and some simple JS/jquery code like

```
$('#acept').click(function(){

    /* if( $("#acept").checked ){
        alert(" I'm checked ");
    } */

    if( this.checked ){
        alert(" I'm checked ");
    }

})
```

Now, the first 'if' (the commented one) doesn't work, but the second one does.
Any explanation as to why?

Comment: In jQuery the proper syntax is `$("#acept").is(':checked')`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960208/jquery-if-checkbox-is-checked

Comment: `$('#acept').prop('checked')` should work, though

Comment: $("#acept") is a jQuery object. You can use .get(0) to get the first element in the object

Comment: `this` is a DOM element and `$("#accept")` returns a jQuery object.

Comment: ... or just `$("#acept")[0].checked`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `$("#acept")` is a jQuery object and does not have any property *checked* on that directly, you can either use *index* or do that using jQuery's builtin methods like `.prop('checked')` or `.is(':checked')`:

```js
$('#acept').click(function(){
  console.log($("#acept").checked); //undefined
  if( $("#acept").is(':checked') ){
    alert(" I'm checked ");
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="checkbox" name="acept" id="acept">
```

Comment: I think in this case OP just wants to know why the first doesn't work; in all practicality, using `this.checked` would be better imo.