# Checked checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a varible `IDs` with 3 checkboxes ids (`#Id1, #Id2, #Id3`).
So when I do `$(IDs)`, I have the list of the checkboxes.

How to know how many checkboxes are checked? I want to trigger the click event on the checked checkboxes.

I try `$(IDs + ":checked").click()` but the `:checked` is only on `#Id3`.

I could do `$(IDs).each(...);` and do in the function the test if it's checked.
Or change the value of `IDs` to this : `#Id1:checked, #Id2:checked, #Id3:checked`.

Is there a way to do it in one line? (or easily)

Thanks

Comment: put a class in each one, make a click event in the class, get the ID and try something `if($(id).is(":checked")){ }` ...

Comment: You can see how to do what you want at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2204275/132528

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
var $checked = $(IDs).filter(':checked');
$checked.click(function() { alert('hello'); });
```