# How can I check if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I am building a mobile web app with jQuery Mobile and I want to check if a checkbox is checked. Here is my code.

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  function validate(){
    if (remember.checked == 1){
      alert("checked") ;
    } else {
      alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
    }
  }
</script>

<input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" />
```

But for some reason or another it doesn't execute it.

Please help !

----EDIT-----
This is what I have for the moment.

```
<DIV data-role="content" data-theme="g">
    <DIV class=ui-grid-g-login>
        <FORM method=post action=[$=PROBE(266)/] data-theme="C">
            <P>~DATA_ERROR~</P>
            <div id="mail" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="mail">Email:*</label>       
                <input id="mail" name="mail" type="email" />
            </div>
            <div id="pass" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="pass">Paswoord:*</label>        
                <input id="pass" name="pass" type="password" />
            </div>
            <div id="remember" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="remember">Onthoud mij</label>       
                <input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" />
            </div>
            <P><INPUT class=btn name=submit value=Login type=submit  onclick="validate()"></P>  
        </FORM>
    </DIV>
</DIV><!-- /content -->

<script type=text/javascript>
function validate(){
    var remember = document.getElementById('remember');
    if (remember.checked){
        alert("checked") ;
    }else{
        alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
    }
}
</script>
```

----EDIT--

Solved it, the problem was that the fieldcontain was also named 'remember'

Comment: What is `remember` in this context: `if (remember.checked == 1){`???

Comment: Later on it should remember email and password. It's for a login page

Comment: What I am trying to say is that `remember` is `undefined` in that context. Try `console.log(remember);`.

Comment: As @Steaphann mentioned in the edit, the code did not work because there are *two* elements with same id in the html. `<div id="remember" data-role="fieldcontain">` and `<input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" />`.
None of the answers caught this issue.

Answer (score 441):

`checked` is a `boolean` property, so you can directly use it in an `if` condition

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById('remember').checked) {
            alert("checked");
        } else {
            alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I always get the message 'You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.'

Comment: Nope its working fine for me ; i am getting both alert messages.

Comment: @Steaphann Did you replace the word 'remember' with your checkbox id? ...oh, just noticed 2012 0.o ...p.s. you forgot the semi-colon after the 2nd alert statement

Comment: @josh.thomson semi-colons are optional.

Answer (score 91):

Try this:

```
function validate() {
  var remember = document.getElementById("remember");
  if (remember.checked) {
    alert("checked");
  } else {
    alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
  }
}
```

Your script doesn't know what the variable `remember` is. You need to get the element first using getElementById().

Comment: You should also advice to strip that `== 1`. Its only working because of two errors. Actually the value is `true` or `false`, he should just using `if( remeber.checked )`

Comment: I always get the message 'You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.'

Answer (score 20):

```
//HTML
<input type="checkbox" id="someID">
```

```
// JavaScript
const someCheckbox = document.getElementById('someID');

someCheckbox.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if(e.target.checked === true) {
    console.log("Checkbox is checked - boolean value: ", e.target.checked)
  }
if(e.target.checked === false) {
    console.log("Checkbox is not checked - boolean value: ", e.target.checked)
  }
});
```

[know more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)

Answer (score 10):

use like this

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    function validate(){
        if (document.getElementById('remember').checked){
            alert("checked") ;
        } else {
            alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
        }
    }
</script>

<input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" />
```

Comment: I always get the message 'You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.'

Comment: @user1251632 WFM too. Can you edit your question and show what you have now? Perhaps you made a copy and paste error.

Comment: document.getElementById('remember').checked == 1 was changed by me bfore your comment.. it may be the problem.

Answer (score 9):

```
if (document.getElementById('remember').checked) {
    alert("checked");
}
else {
    alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This should allow you to determine if an element with `id='remember'` is `'checked'`:

```
if (document.getElementById('remember').is(':checked'))
```

Comment: `is` does not belong to the DOM element object

Comment: `.is()` - is a jQuery function. `.checked` is javascript.

Comment: Why does this have so many upvotes? Between the missing parenthesis and the mix between vanilla and jquery. The answer is terrible
It's either `$('#remember').is(':checked')` or `document.getElementById('remember').checked` but mixing will never work

Answer (score 8):

If you are using this form for mobile app then you may use the required attribute html5. 
you dont want to use any java script validation for this. It should work

```
<input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" required="required" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this below simple code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Divyesh_Patel/v7a4h3kr/7/

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<a href="#" onclick="check()">click</a>
<button onclick="check()">button</button>
<script>
  function check() {
    if (document.getElementById('check').checked) {
      alert("checked");
    } else {
      alert("Not checked.");
    }

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work

```
function validate() {
    if ($('#remeber').is(':checked')) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
        alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using this and it works for me with **Jquery**:

**Jquery:**

```
var checkbox = $('[name="remember"]');

if (checkbox.is(':checked'))
{
    console.log('The checkbox is checked');
}else
{
    console.log('The checkbox is not checked');
}
```

Is very simple, but work's.

Regards!

Answer (score 3):

`remember` is undefined … and the `checked` property is a boolean not a number.

```
function validate(){
    var remember = document.getElementById('remember');
    if (remember.checked){
        alert("checked") ;
    }else{
        alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this below simple code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Divyesh_Patel/v7a4h3kr/7/

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<a href="#" onclick="check()">click</a>
<button onclick="check()">
button
</button>
<script>
  function check() {
    if (document.getElementById('check').checked) {
      alert("checked");
    } else {
      alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
    }

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple and effective code using pure JS and jQuery.

**using validate function as `onclick attr`**

```js
function validate(el) {
    if (el.checked) {
        alert("checked")
    } else {
        alert("unchecked")
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" onclick="validate(this)" />
```

**OR**

`using pure JS`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    //using pure Js code
    let chk = document.getElementById("remember");
    if (chk.checked) {
        alert("checked")
    }else{
        alert("unchecked")
    }
})
```

```html
<input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox"/>
```

`using jQuery`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //using jQuery code
    $('#remember').on('change', function (e) {
        if (e.currentTarget.checked) {
            alert("checked")
        } else {
            alert("unchecked")
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I recommend you to use attr `onclick`  or use jQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if ($('#remember').is(':checked')){
   alert('checked');
}else{
   alert('not checked')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `remember` variable is undefined. so try this way:

```
function validate() {
  var remember = document.getElementById("remember");
  if (remember.checked) {
    alert("checked");
  } else {
    alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');

    function check() {
        if (input.checked) {
            alert("checked");
        } else {
            alert("You didn't check it.");
        }
    }
    input.onchange = check;
    check();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use JQuery methods to accomplish this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($('#remember')[0].checked) 
{
 alert("checked");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -4):

The below will definitely work. updated 2022

```
<input onchange="isChecked()" type="checkbox" required="required"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
        let ischeckvariable = false;
    function isChecked() {
        if (!ischeckvariable) {
            ischeckvariable = true;
        } else {
            isckeckvariable = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```