# ASP.Net - Getting span values for form fields on error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, html

I have asp.net form with text boxes and drop downs. I do client side validation for these controls on a button click.

For example, to validate the below firstname textbox, I am using jquery to check for no input and valid characters. If textbox is empty first `<span>` will be displayed. If invalid characters are typed second `<span>` will be displayed. Now on the button click I want to get the error message shown (anyone one ).

```
<asp:TextBox ID="firstNameTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<span class="validation validation-checkEmpty">Please enter your first name.</span>
<span class="validation validation-checkValidChars">We can only accept letters, apostrophes, and hyphens for your first name.</span>
```

I have to do this for all textboxes, drop downs, checkboxes in the form.

So my question is how to get the error message shown in `<span>` when the validation fails. I have to do this for all controls in the form.

Can anyone guide me in the right way.

Thanks,

Arul

Answer (score 1):

You need to give id in your spa tag, and write a javascrpt method o ontextchange event of thext bosex.then depending on your input, you should hide/show your correspondin span tag.

Here is an example : 
[how to hide a <span> tag and show it with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887526/how-to-hide-a-span-tag-and-show-it-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Acutally I have already done with the validation part. Now I have to send all error messages to google analytics for each input which has validation failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/registration" method="POST">
 <p>
  Name (4 characters minimum):
  <input name="user" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4">
 </p>
 <p>
  Year (yyyy-mm-dd):
  <input name="birth" data-validation="date" data-validation-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
 </p>
 <p>
  Website:
  <input name="website" data-validation="url">
 </p>
 <p>
  <input type="submit">
 </p>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<script> $.validate(); </script>
```

You can take a look at demo on,
http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a validation function like this:
    function validateEntries() {
        var err = 0;
        var errmsg = "Please fix the following errors:";
        if ($.("#" + ").val() == '') {
           err = 1;
           errmsg = errmsg + "\n" + "First name is missing";
        }
        if (err > 0) {
           alert (errmsg);
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    }