# Check if is it checked on - <input type='checkbox'>

Tags: javascript, html, dom, checkbox

I try to do as describe in - [check if checkbox is checked javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-javascript)

And this is my code -

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.name = "test";
input.type = "checkbox";
input.checked = true ;
var currentInput = document.getElementsByName("test");
if (currentInput.checked) {
    console.log("true");
}
```

but after run it nothing logs to the console although the `input.checked = true` assignment.

Why doesn't it logs `true` ?

**Edit:**

According to what @adeneo and @mori57 said , now the follow  -

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.name = "test";
input.type = "checkbox";
input.checked = true;
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild(input);
var currentInput = document.getElementsByName("test")[0];
if (currentInput.checked) {
    console.log("true");
}
```

logs `true`

Comment: getElementsByName('test')[0] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `document.getElementsByName("test")` returns an array, so you would need to use a certain element of the array:

If it is the only one, you can just select the first one:

```
document.getElementsByName("test")[0]
```

So, your new code would be:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.name = "test";
input.type = "checkbox";
input.checked = true ;
var currentInput = document.getElementsByName("test")[0];
if (currentInput.checked) {
    console.log("true");
}
```

*As pointed out by **mori57**'s comment*,

You never actually create the element, causing it to not be possible to be discovered.  You would need to use something such as:

```
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

Before declaring `currentInput` in order for it to be able to be found.

Comment: Am I the only one who has noticed OP's code doesn't add the element to the DOM? DOM can't find what or doesn't contain....

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see `getElements..`, as in plural, and not `getElement...` it means you're getting a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) not a single element, even if there is only one element in that [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

You can access [nodeLists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) like arrays, so `nodeList[0]` is the first element in the list

```
var currentInput = document.getElementsByName("test")[0];
```

Of course, you already have a reference to the element, so you don't have to get it again

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.name = "test";
input.type = "checkbox";
input.checked = true ;

if (input.checked) { // this will always be true, so it makes no sense
    console.log("true");
}
```

and as pointed out in the comment by @mori57, you never add the element to the DOM, so you can't get it with `document.getEleme....` methods when it doesn't exist.

I'm guessing what you really want is an event handler

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.name = "test";
input.type = "checkbox";
input.checked = true ;

input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log( this.checked );
}, false);
```