# Radio button validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

**This is my form**

```
   Select Staff : <select name="Staff" id="Staff"><br />
   <option value="Staff">Select Staff</option>
```

The validation for the form is as simple this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
function validateMyForm ( ) { 
    var isValid = true;
    if ( document.form1.Name.value == "" ) { 
        alert ( "Please type your Name" ); 
        isValid = false;
    }  else if ( document.form1.Staff.value == "Staff" ) { 
            alert ( "Please choose Staff" ); 
            isValid = false;
    } 
    return isValid;
}
</script>
```

How do I validate radio buttons using JS ?

Comment: Buddy u can search this in Google as well...

Comment: Its very much silly thing... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-javascript how abt this/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="question" id="question_yes" value="Yes" />Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="question" id="question_no" value="No" />No

<script>
if(document.getElementById('question_yes').checked) {
  // yes is checked
}else if(document.getElementById('question_no').checked) {
  // no is checked
}
</script>
```

Here's a jsFiddle to show you how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/A3fg8/