# How can I ensure a tick box has been ticked before continuing?

Tags: javascript, forms

How can I ensure that a tick box is ticked before letting a form process?

```html
I confirm I am at least 18 years old, and have read the website terms and conditions
<input type="checkbox" name="confirm" value="confirm">
```

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-javascript