# Show/hide input field based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

If the checkbox is clicked it will display an input field... so far it it is working, But if the checkbox is unchecked it should hide it, how can i do it?

```
    <div class="checkbox"> 
    <label class="checkbox-custom"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="clases" id="clases" value="yes">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-square-o"></i> Doy clases particulares/grupales
    </label> 
    </div>


    <div class="input" id="descripcion">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Descripcion</label>
   <textarea type="textarea" rows="7" cols="" class="form-control"  name="descripcion" placeholder="" required></textarea>
    </div>
```

Here is the script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#descripcion").hide();
    $("#clases").click(function () {
    $("#descripcion").show();
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#clases").change(function () {
   $("#descripcion").toggle();
});
```