# Hide html from when checkbox is checked via php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

In my project I have a `HTML` page, some part of `HTML` file should display when a `checkbox` is `checked`, I used a `Form` `tag` cause I should `submit` that parameters to the server.
Here is that part of `HTML` file : ( The `HTML` file name is `config.html`)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="advancecheck" id="advancecheck" onchange="valueChanged()">
<br>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    function valueChanged()
    {
        if($('.advancecheck').is(":checked"))   
            $(".subnetmaskdiv").show();
        else
            $(".subnetmaskdiv").hide();
    }
</script>
<form action="" method="post" name="subnet">
    <div id="subnetmaskdiv">
        <label>Subnet Mask</label>
        <input type="text" name="subnetmask" id="subnetmask">
        <br>
    </div>
</form>
```

I did that in `HTML` file.
I include this `HTML` file in my `Php` file : ( My Php file name is configwireless.php )

I tried different ways to do this, But no chance.
Could anybody tell me what is the correct way by a simple sample?
Any help will appreciate.
thanks to all.

Comment: Add your code what you tried, we all are here to give suggestion and solve not for doing your code. :)

Comment: to hide html when you check a checkbox you need to use javascript

Comment: I can't understand your question, what do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: Where is your checkbox?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853803/show-hide-input-field-based-on-checkbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, hope to work

```
<input type="checkbox" name="advancecheck" id="advancecheck" 
onchange="valueChanged()"/><br>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function valueChanged() {
      if (document.getElementById('advancecheck').checked) {
          document.getElementById("subnetmaskdiv").style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        document.getElementById("subnetmaskdiv").style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

</script>

<form action="" method="post" name="subnet">
  <div id="subnetmaskdiv" style="display:none;">
    <label>Subnet Mask</label>
    <input type="text" name="subnetmask" id="subnetmask"><br>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Such a great Idea! Thanks
And I want if i uncheck it disappear again.
I change the code to 

    `function valueChanged(){
    if (document.getElementById('advancecheck').checked) 
        {
            document.getElementById("subnetmaskdiv").style.display = 'block';
        } else if(! (document.getElementById('advancecheck').checked)) {
    elsedocument.getElementById("subnetmaskdiv").style.display = 'none';
    }
    }`
But no chance,

Comment: you don't need to change the code. 
In my code, if checkbox is clicked, 'div' will appear.
if it is not checked, "div" will disappear

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<div id="autoUpdate" class="autoUpdate">
   content
</div>
```

Checkbox here:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
```

And if you want to hide that `div` on checkbox click, then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#checkbox1').change(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#autoUpdate').hide();
        }

    });
</script>
```

This is just an example for your reference.

Comment: I edited the question.
I am brand new to Php and this a force project.
Where should I do your code?
In the html file or in php file?
I have separate them.