# Rails check_box_tag - get all the values checked in view(haml) file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

So I have multiple checkboxes on my page. I collect all of them like shown in the code below. I would like to access the values of the array before passing it on to the controller

```
= check_box_tag "names[]", ob.name, false, class: 'cbx'
```

I am able to pass them with my older code

```
%fieldset.actions
  = form.submit "Upgrade", :class => 'button'
```

Logs:

> Processing by SomeController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "names"=>["ron", "jacob"],  "commit"=>"NameButton"}

Ok. So i would like to access all values in my haml files. Is there a way before i submit my form, I can access which checkboxes are selected.

I would like to pass the names[] to my controller as a parameter.

```
=link_to script_name1, { :action => 'create', :names => 'dontknowhowtopassnames[]' }, :method => :post
```

Rails version - 3.2.17

Comment: You can, with Javascript/jQuery. [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-javascript)

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: I need to pass the names[] to my controller as a parameter. I had it working with a form submit. But i had to change that logic. Now i am passing the parameters to my controller. But i don;t know how to pass in the names[] directly to my controller

Comment: So what you really want is to submit the form using a link instead of a button? Because that's really trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using Javascript.
The exact implementation depends on **what** exactly you want to do with those values, but you could, for example, use the `change` event to track and maintain an array of all checked values :

```
/*
* should properly init this array if some of your checkboxes are already
* checked when the form is loaded
*/
var names = [];

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('change', '.cbx', function() {
    var name = $(this).val();
    var idx = names.indexOf(name);
    if ($(this).prop('checked') && idx === -1) {
      names.push(name);
    } else if (!($(this).prop('checked')) && idx >= 0) {
      names.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  });

});
```

Updated with complementary answer:

To submit a form with a link instead of a button:

In your view, replace

```
%fieldset.actions
  = form.submit "Upgrade", :class => 'button'
```

with

```
= link_to "Submit", "#", :class => 'submit_link'
```

Then in your Javascript, add the following inside the `$(document).ready` body:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.submit_link', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

And that's it. You're making your life very complicated by trying to serialize the form data on your own while the form's `submit()` method can take care of it for you. You **can** serialize data on your own, and it's sometimes useful, for instance when dealing with AJAX, but in your case the default `submit()` is perfect for the job.

Comment: Thanks jaxx. Is there any way i can view the values in my haml file.I need to pass the names[] to my controller as a parameter.

Comment: Sorry Anish, I don't get it. You are already passing the selected names as an array to your controller, as the logs you posted show :

Processing by SomeController#create as HTML Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", **"names"=>["ron", "jacob"]**, "commit"=>"NameButton"}

Comment: As for viewing & updating the selected names on your page as boxes get checked/unchecked, yes, that's easily doable, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: I know they were working with my older code..             %fieldset.actions
    = form.submit "Upgrade", :class => 'button'                                                     But i don't know how to pass them with my new code..                          =link_to script_name1, { :action => 'create', :names => 'dontknowhowtopassnames[]' }, :method => :post

Comment: See updated answer. I believe you're overthinking the whole issue.