# console log if checkbox has been checked?

Tags: javascript, html

Im having trouble getting the console to log when the checkbox has been selected or not.

HTML:

```
<label class="container">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

JS:

```
function carDealer () {

        if (document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox1').checked == true) {
            console.log('true');

            } else {
                console.log('false');
            }
    }
    carDealer();
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox1')[0]` `getElementsByClassName` gives out an array of DOM nodes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if checkbox is checked JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns array like object, so please replace

```
document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox1').checked == true
```

to

```
document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox1')[0].checked == true
```

Comment: or, simply to: `document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox1')[0].checked` (without the `== true`)

Comment: thanks, problem solved! I also was expecting the console to automatically update upon checked/not checked but then I realized I needed to hit the submit button for it to update woops.