# How to get a value from a Html radio button

Tags: javascript, html, button, electron, return-value

I have a html radio button, but I want to know how can I get a value from it. (I'm working on Electron)

Here is my Radio code

```
 <label class="container">Ne plus afficher cette page au lancement.<input type="checkbox" unchecked="uncheck"><span class="checkmark"></span>
```

Basically I want to call a funtion if the box is checked.

for exemple

```
Function typeFunction(){

//load a window (Not sure if this is right
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

}
```

Comment: You say you are working with a radio button, but your code shows a checkbox.  You also have invalid HTML with the `unchecked` attribute. Next, you say you want the value, but then you say that you want to know if it is checked. Then, you show invalid JavaScript with `Function`, rather than `function`. Please update your question to be more concise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a checkbox is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/how-can-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked)

Comment: To get a value from a check box or radio button, it must have a `value` attribute. You are missing this from your code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to remove that `unchecked` tag its useless.
Secondly, give a class to the checkbox for example " checkButton ".
Lastly, you need to select the Item from the DOM.

```
const checkBtn = document.querySelector('.checkButton');
```

If you want to DO something when the checkbox is checked you just need to use the .checked property ->

```
 if(checkBtn.checked) {
 // do something 
} else {
 // do something else 
 }
```

Also use `function` because if you are gonna use it with capital ,,F'' JS is gonna think this is a `function constructor`.

Comment: A constructor function is just a regular function (lower case "f") that is called with the `new` keyword. You might be referring to using the "function constructor" (rather than a constructor function), which is `var myFunc = new Function("body here");`.

Answer (score 0):

Give ids to each choice.

id="choice1"

Then get the value by referring to the said id.   choice1.value