# Trying to check if any checkbox on the page is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check if any checkbox on the website has been checked when text has been entered in the name text box. I know that the EventListener works for name since this works without the document.getElementsByName("event[]").checked, but how do I make it work for the checkboxes?

```js
document.getElementsByName("name")[0].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.value.length != 0 && document.getElementsByName("event[]").checked ) {
  window.alert("checked");
 }
})
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
  <section id="Events">
    <h2>Select Events</h2>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 1</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>10.50</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='1' data-price='10.50'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 2</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>5.00</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='2' data-price='5.00'></span>
    </div>
    <section id="Cost">
      <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="ticket" data-price="10">
      <h2>Total Price</h2>
      Total Price <input type="text" name="total" size="12">
      <p>Name<input type="text" name="name"></p>
    </section>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book"></p>
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/how-can-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
document.getElementsByName("name")[0].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  // here we used event.target.value.trim.length in order to guard against
  // white-space strings being considered valid (if that's not a problem
  // then the trim() method can be removed), and also we used:
  // document.querySelector() to find the first of any <input> element
  // with a type equal to 'checkbox' which is also checked;
  // document.querySelector() returns either the first such element or null:
  if (event.target.value.trim().length > 0 && 
      document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]:checked') !== null) {
    window.alert("checked");
  }
});
```

```js
document.getElementsByName("name")[0].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.value.trim().length > 0 &&
    document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]:checked') !== null) {
    window.alert("checked");
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
  <section id="Events">
    <h2>Select Events</h2>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 1</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>10.50</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='1' data-price='10.50'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 2</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>5.00</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='2' data-price='5.00'></span>
    </div>
    <section id="Cost">
      <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="ticket" data-price="10">
      <h2>Total Price</h2>
      Total Price <input type="text" name="total" size="12">
      <p>Name<input type="text" name="name"></p>
    </section>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book"></p>
  </section>
</form>
```

It's worth adding that your first line could be potentially simplified a little using `document.querySelector()` rather than using indices:

```
document.querySelector("input[name=name]").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.value.trim().length > 0 && 
      document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]:checked') !== null) {
    window.alert("checked");
  }
});
```

```js
document.querySelector('input[name=name]').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.value.trim().length > 0 &&
    document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]:checked') !== null) {
    window.alert("checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
  <section id="Events">
    <h2>Select Events</h2>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 1</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>10.50</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='1' data-price='10.50'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <span class='eventTitle'>Event number 2</span>
      <span class='eventPrice'>5.00</span>
      <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='2' data-price='5.00'></span>
    </div>
    <section id="Cost">
      <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="ticket" data-price="10">
      <h2>Total Price</h2>
      Total Price <input type="text" name="total" size="12">
      <p>Name<input type="text" name="name"></p>
    </section>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book"></p>
  </section>
</form>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors (`[attribute=attribute-value]`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).
  - [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Answer (score 0):

```
//--Get all checkboxes, you can have another way of fetching checkboxes
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
//--For each checkbox, check if it is selected
for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkBoxes[i].checked == true) {
        alert('checked');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document.querySelectorAll to get an array containing all the checkbox inputs in the document:

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
```

Then, to check if **any** of the checkboxes are checked:

```js
var anyChecked = false;
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
    anyChecked = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want an array containing only the checkboxes that are checked, you can do the following:

```js
var checkedCheckboxes = checkboxes.filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName("name")[0].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
 if(event.target.value.length !== 0) {
  // Get all checkboxes  
  const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("event[]");
  for(i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
    // Check if checkbox is checked or not
    if(checkboxes[i].checked) {
     window.alert("checked");
    }
  }
 }
})
```