# how to create dataset with use checkbox dom javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox, dataset, queryselector

please help me I don't know create dataset with use checkbox,, this is my source code:

```
const isCompleted    = document.querySelector('[data-input-Book-IsComplete]:checked');
```

how should it be...?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by *"create dataset with use checkbox"*? Do you want to check if the checkbos is checked: [How can I check if a checkbox is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the value of the data attribute.

```js
const isCompleted = document
  .querySelector('input[data-input="Book-IsComplete"]:checked')
  .checked;

console.log(isCompleted); // true
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-input="Book-IsComplete" checked />
```

if you want to check the dataset, you can try the following:

```js
const isCompleted = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')]
  .find(checkbox => checkbox.dataset.input === 'Book-IsComplete')?.checked ?? false;

console.log(isCompleted); // true
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-input="Book-IsComplete" checked />
```