# Html sidebar function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to implement my code by changing only the check box to a button in the same way as the function?And how do I make js code onclick instead of css? Could you tell me both?

```
<style>
* {
    padding:0;margin:0;
}

.sidebar{
    width:300px;height:100%;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    position:fixed;top:0;
    right:-300px;z-index:1;
    transition:all .35s;}
#menuicon:checked + div {
    right:0;
}

</style>
<input type="checkbox" id="menuicon">
<div class="sidebar">
</div>
```

I tried to implement the onclick function by changing the check box to a button and using javascript, but the function did not work I want to make it with JavaScript only

Comment: Duplicate Question.
Original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/how-can-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a checkbox is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/how-can-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked)

Comment: Please show us the code that did not work. And have you checked in your browsers devtools inspect facility console that there are no errors?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code below...

**First in HTML**

In the markup, we have a sidebar open `button class="opened"`, a sidebar close button `button class="closed"` and the sidebar itself `div class="sidebar"` inside the `aside` semantic tag. Note that the close button for the panel is inside the panel itself. Those. it appears on the user's screen only when the panel is open, which is logical.

**Now take a look at the CSS**

The visual styles of the buttons are not particularly interesting. Interesting sidebar styles. It is positioned fixedly relative to the browser window. In order for the panel to occupy the entire height of the screen, the `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` properties are set. In addition, by default, we hide the panel outside the visible area using our `transform: translateX(-100%)` property. The percentage sizes for this property are calculated based on the size of the block to which it is applied. Those. -100% shifts the panel to the left by its full width.
Notice the `.sidebar.active` selector. It will take effect when the sidebar has both the `.sidebar` class and the `.active` class. In this selector, we remove the shift of the sidebar outside the visible area. This means that the sidebar with the `.active` class is visible to the user.

**Now let's take a look at JS**

First, we define the identifiers of the elements we need - the open, close and sidebar buttons. This will be needed for what follows. Obviously, when the open button is clicked, we need to add the active class to the sidebar. We defined the function of adding this class for the click event in the `addEventListener` method.
On the close button we hang a click listener and a deletion function of the `.active` class for the sidebar.

Here's a simple technique.

```js
const open = document.querySelector('.opened');
const close = document.querySelector('.closed');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

open.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidebar.classList.add('active');
});
close.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidebar.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.opened,
.closed {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #e9e9ed;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: .2s;
}

.closed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.sidebar.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<button class="opened"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 6h-24v-4h24v4zm0 4h-24v4h24v-4zm0 8h-24v4h24v-4z"/></svg></button>
<aside>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <button class="closed"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M23 20.168l-8.185-8.187 8.185-8.174-2.832-2.807-8.182 8.179-8.176-8.179-2.81 2.81 8.186 8.196-8.186 8.184 2.81 2.81 8.203-8.192 8.18 8.192z"/></svg></button>
  </div>
</aside>
```