# How to use jquery to validate whether at least one tick box from #age-groups, #subjects and #topics have been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

In my upload form I have a few select boxes. These are arranged in divs called #age-groups, #subjects and #topics.

I want to be able to use jquery to make sure the user clicks at least one checkbox from each of the 3 individual divs.

Please could someone help me figure out how to do this.

For when at least one checkbox in each div is clicked I want the function to output:

```
   if (at least 1 checkbox is ticked in each of the 3 divs)
   {
     $('#two')
         .append('<div class="done rotatetwo wiggler"></div>')
         .addClass('grey')
   }
```

If possible can this function output the above code as soon as the final required select box is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
    if (($("#age-groups input:checked").length>0) && ($("#subjects input:checked").length>0) && ($("#topics input:checked").length>0){
        $('#two').append('<div class="done rotatetwo wiggler"></div>').addClass('grey');
    }
});
```

Comment: This was the most straightforward method and it worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the parents of check box/select box for determination.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/jquery-check-if-checkbox-is-checked)

basically,

HTML

```
<fieldset id="age-groups">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Apples" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Bananas" />
</fieldset>
```

JavaScript/Jquery

```
 var atLeastOneIsChecked_ageGroups = $('#age-groups :checkbox:checked').length > 0;
```

will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use three selectors to identify any checked checkboxes inside of your three DIVs, then examine the `length` property of the resulting jQuery objects to make sure that they're greater than zero.

```
if($('#age-groups input:checkbox:checked').length && ... ) {
    // do your stuff here
}
```

I've only included the selector for the `#age-groups` div, but you should be able to modify that to select for the other two.

Answer (score 0):

-- misread the question. This would help you if you wanted to check if at least one box is selected across all relevant divs.

try something like this:

```
if($("#age-groups input[name^='foo']:checked:enabled, #subjects input[name^='foo']:checked:enabled, #topics input[name^='foo']:checked:enabled").length > 0)
// at least one selected
else
// none selected
```

Of course, this can be simplified if you add a class to all check boxes instead of using the parent div to group them.

```
if( $("input[name^='foo'].test:checked:enabled").length > 0)
// something selected
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: They asked for at least one checkbox selected in **each** div, not at least one checkbox selected between the three divs.

Comment: Fair. But, the same principle applies.