# How to know whether checkbox is checked or not, jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any better way to do this :

```
var IsC = $('input[type=checkbox]').attr("checked") == "checked" ? true : false;
```

?

Comment: You have to be more precise about what you want to test. Do you want to know where there is a checkbox that is checked or whether a specific one is checked? Your code will only test whether the first one is checked (which is ok as long as you don't have more than one). But apart from that I'm quite certain this has been asked before here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery - Check if checkbox is checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/jquery-check-if-checkbox-is-checked)

Comment: Anyone with 1k rep or higher should be ashamed answering this... probably one of the most asked questions.. you are just rep farming

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
var IsC = $('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked");
```

Or :

```
var IsC = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length>0;
```

Comment: `.is()` also returns `true` if at least one is checked. http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var IsC = $('input[type=checkbox]').attr("checked") == "checked" ? true : false;
```

is the same as just saying:

```
var IsC = $('input[type=checkbox]').attr("checked") == "checked";
```

since `==` will return `true` or `false`. (purely a javascript change)

---

The jQuery optimization (in terms of number of characters, at least) is:

```
var IsC = $('input:checkbox').is(':checked'); 
//returns true if at least one checkbox in the document is checked
```

You can add a scope for the comparison by telling the selector where the input should be found:

```
var IsC = $('#myForm input:checkbox').is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use solution posted by [dystroy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11431187/219217).

Another is to use `prop` method instead of `attr`. Check examples at http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
elem.checked
// true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state

$(elem).prop("checked")
// true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state

elem.getAttribute("checked")
// "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change

$(elem).attr("checked") //(1.6)
// "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change

$(elem).attr("checked") //(1.6.1+)
// "checked" (String) Will change with checkbox state

$(elem).attr("checked") //(pre-1.6)
// true (Boolean) Changed with checkbox state
```