# adding check all and uncheck all option using value inside checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a select all, unselect all options like we see in email inboxes for a group of checkboxes. I have added an example for this. The working model that I am trying to get is when a I click on checkbox, it should select and unselect that group with a particular value. Also even if we uncheck any single name form the list, it should uncheck the main "select all" checkbox.  I've added a jsfiddle, but it doesnt work properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectAll").live("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var clickedValue=$(this).attr('class');
        clickedValue=clickedValue.replace("select", "");
        $("#modalEntity").attr("value", "group"+ clickedValue).attr("checked", true);      
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EBxSu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code a bit removing multiple IDs and handling the various scenario requested (clearing the select all check box if user selects a child). Also updated your jQuery using .on() rather than .live().

jQuery looks like:

```
$(function(){
  $('.selectAll').on('click', function(evt){
    var group = $(this).attr('data-group'),
        isChecked = !!($(this).prop('checked'));
    $('input[value="' + group + '"]').prop('checked', isChecked);    
  })

  $('.entity').on('click', function(evt){
    var group = $(this).attr('value'),
        siblings = $('input[value="' + group + '"]'),
        isChecked = true;
    siblings.each(function(idx, el){
      if(!$(el).prop('checked')) {
        isChecked = false;
        return;
      }
    })
    $('.selectAll[data-group="' + group + '"]').prop('checked', isChecked);
  })
})
```

And the updated HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
Country
<ul>
<input type="checkbox" class="selectAll" data-group="group1">Select/Deselect All Country
<li>
<input class="entity" type="checkbox" value="group1" name="India">India
<input class="entity" type="checkbox" value="group1" name="UAE">UAE
...
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nBh4L/2/

Thanks!
Jack

Comment: Please post your code also here, at least the relevant parts.

Comment: Is it possible to get the details( id, class, name) of the child checkboxes associated each main checkbox while clicking on select all option..

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** (*changed live to on & some renaming*)

First, you should never have elements with the same ID like this:

```
<input id="modalEntity" class="entity1" type="checkbox" value="group1" name="India">India
<input id="modalEntity" class="entity2" type="checkbox" value="group1" name="UAE">UAE
```

I rewrote the jQuery code to this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    $("input.select").on("click", function() {
        $(this).siblings().find("input.entity").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
    });

    $("input.entity").on("click", function() {
        var $entityGroup = $(this).siblings().andSelf();
        $(this).parent().siblings("input.select").prop("checked", $entityGroup.length === $entityGroup.filter(":checked").length);
    });
});
```

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) should only be used on jQuery 1.6 and above.

I also rewrote you HTML a bit, look at the updated jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sQVe/EBxSu/8/

Just comment if I missed something, but I think this is what you're after.

Comment: Just a nitpick: it's entities, not entitys. And, my mother tongue is also not English. :-)

Comment: @nalply you are oh-so-correct. English is not my native tongue either so, updated the post.

Comment: Good catch, Vins, I didn't know that live has been deprecated. We are all here to learn.

Comment: @Vins Totally missed that he used `.live()`. Updated the post to use `.on()` instead. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand you solution, but here's one. First, keep similar groups of buttons with a common attribute, say `relation`, having a value of **child**. Then keep the selector/deselector for that group with the same name but the value of `relation` attribute set to **parent**. Now you have to

1.Toggle the state of all similar child checkboxes when the mother's state is toggled:

```
$("[relation=parent]").change(function() {
 name = $(this).prop('name');
  $("[relation=child][name="+name+"]").attr('checked',$(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

2.Toggle the mother's state accordingly when a child's state is toggled:

```
$("[relation=parent]").change(function() {
 name = $(this).attr('name');
 $("[relation=child][name="+name+"]").attr('checked',$(this).attr('checked'));
});
$("[relation=child]").change(function() {
 name = $(this).attr('name');
 if ($(this).attr('checked') == false) {
   $("[relation=parent][name="+name+"]").attr('checked',false);
  }
 else {
   if ($("[name="+name+"][relation=child]:checked").length == $("[name="+name+"][relation=child]").length) {
     $("[name="+name+"][relation=parent]").attr('checked','true');
    }
   }
  });
```

Comment: Ummm, where are the errors? I will correct the formatting. Always a problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have done that for countries only. Html:

```
<ul>
<li>
Country
<ul>
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" class="select1">Select/Deselect All Country
<li>
<input class="entity1 countries" type="checkbox" value="group1" name="India">India
<input class="entity2 countries" type="checkbox" value="group1" name="UAE">UAE
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#selectAll").click(function(){
    if(!$('.countries').attr('checked'))
        $('.countries').attr('checked','checked');
    else
        $('.countries').removeAttr('checked');
});
$('.countries').click(function(){
    var allChecked = true;
    $('.countries').each(function(index, element){
       if(!$(element).attr('checked'))
           allChecked = false;
    });
    if(!allChecked)
        $("#selectAll").removeAttr('checked');        
    else
        $("#selectAll").attr('checked','checked');         
});
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your JS fiddle with a more correct soltuion:

http://jsfiddle.net/EBxSu/2/

There are a few things that I would like you point out that you are doing wrong, and maybe it will help you with this:

- You were using HTML "id" and class" attributes wrong. ID should be unique. Class need not be unique - I switched them around for you.
- You don't need to prevent default unless you don't want the checkbox to be checked.
- You had a  with text inside a  tag - this is not valid. Only

  can exist within a  tag - so I moved it out side of the

  jQuery should not be complicated. It can be very simple. I moved the HTML around a bit (check the link).

Your javascript code is now simply:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".selectAll").click(function(e) {
        $(this).siblings('ul').find('input').attr('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

ID's are meant to be unique per page, but ignoring some of the mark-up problems with your code, I have edited it so it works as you intended. http://jsfiddle.net/xYWWM/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectAll").live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var clickedValue = $(this).attr('class');
        clickedValue = clickedValue.replace("select", "");
        var checkboxes = $("#modalEntity[value=\"group" + clickedValue + "\"]");
        checkboxes.attr("checked", !checkboxes.attr("checked"));
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this Tutorial**

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/multiple-checkbox-select-deselect-jquery-tutorial-example/

**Also, Check out this** [Fiddle for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vijaysarin/nPXHK/5/)

**Here is the HTML used in the Demo,**

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
    <th>Cell phone</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/></td>
    <td>BlackBerry Bold 9650</td>
    <td>2/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="2"/></td>
    <td>Samsung Galaxy</td>
    <td>3.5/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="3"/></td>
    <td>Droid X</td>
    <td>4.5/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="4"/></td>
    <td>HTC Desire</td>
    <td>3/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="5"/></td>
    <td>Apple iPhone 4</td>
    <td>5/5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Here is the jQuery for the Demo**

```
$(function(){

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function(){

        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you should note while write you code.
 1. Keep it simple.
 2. Do not use `id` multiple times
 3. Write a html code. Nesting `<ul><inputl><li>` is not a good idea.

This is simplified solution, which hopefully you'll be able to understand and will be able to implement in later at different situation.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="btn-select-all-1">Select/un-select All
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="select1">item1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="select1">item1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="select1">item1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="select1">item1</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var btnSelectAll = $("#btn-select-all-1");
    var toSelect = $('.select1')

     //monitor the select_all checkbox for changes
     //and take appropriate action
    btnSelectAll.on('click', function(){
        if(btnSelectAll.is(":checked")){
          toSelect.attr("checked", "checked");
        }else{
          toSelect.removeAttr("checked");
        }
      });

});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U8aFU/

more help and links:
[Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/jquery-check-if-checkbox-is-checked)
[Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your HTML slightly since you used same ID twice ...Below is the working script...

```
<ul><li>
Country
<ul>
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll1" class="selectAll">Select/Deselect All Country
<li>
<input id="modalEntity1" class="entity" type="checkbox" value="group1"   name="India">India
<input id="modalEntity2" class="entity" type="checkbox" value="group1" name="UAE">UAE
</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>Company<ul>
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll2" class='selectAll'>Select/Deselect All Company</a>
<li>
<input id="modalEntity3" class="entity" type="checkbox" value="group2" name="Apple">Apple
<input id="modalEntity4" class="entity" type="checkbox" value="group2" name="Google">Google
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.selectAll').click(function(){
  var thisStatus = $(this).attr('checked');
    if(thisStatus=='checked'){        
       $(this).parent('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked','checked');
    }
    else{
       $(this).parent('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',false);
    }
});

$('input.entity').click(function(){
var thisStatus = $(this).attr('checked');
    if(thisStatus!=='checked'){
       $(this).parent().parent('ul').find('input.selectAll').attr('checked',false);
    }
    else{
        $("input.entity:checked").each(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent('ul').find('input.selectAll').attr('checked','checked');   
    });
    }

    });
 });​
```