# jQuery: check if checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I want to highlight any unchecked checkboxes when a form is submitted. I've got a total of six checkboxes in `.new_order`, and I've started writing the function but I'm a bit stuck how to add a highlight class to **each** unchecked checkbox in `.new_order`.

```
$('#orderconfirm').click(function () {
    if ($('.modal .modal-body .new_order :checkbox').is(':unchecked') {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

Will this code iterate through each checkbox? I feel like I'm missing something. Also, this code has to disable the button until each checkbox is checked. Any help would be great!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery

Comment: your `.is()` will return true if _any_ box is unchecked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `:not(:checked)` at the end of your selector, call `.addClass()` on this to add the class to all objects returned.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RtpKB/)

```
$('#orderconfirm').click(function () {
    $('.modal .modal-body .new_order input:checkbox:not(:checked)')
        .addClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RtpKB/1/) of the following method.

You could use jQuery's [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate through your class, and add your CSS class to whichever elements meet your criteria:

```
$('#orderconfirm').click(function () {
  $('.new_order').each(function(){
     if($(this).prop('checked') === false) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
     }
  });
});
```