# is :checked not working while using Jquery 1.7

Tags: jquery

Look at this simple code

---

html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" >&nbsp;<span id="rm">Remember
me</span> <span id="ok">Okay!</span>
```

css

```
#ok{
position:absolute;
font:italic bold 14px century;
color:green;
margin-left:3px;
margin-top:2px;
display:inline-block;
opacity:0;
}
```

Jquery

```
if($('#check').is(":checked"))
    {
    $("#ok").css("opacity",1);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/milanshah93/4Hf9T/

It is not working when I check the box.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4Hf9T/10/ you replaced `id` with `is`, and the input has to be checked initially to get the class. What you really need is a change event.

Comment: `if ( document.getElementById('check').checked ) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

Your checkbox was not checked on page load. although you can do something like this -

```
$("#check").on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#ok").css("opacity", 1);
    }
    else{
     $("#ok").css("opacity", 0);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4Hf9T/11/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a working `jsfiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/4Hf9T/14/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check">&nbsp;<span id="rm">Remember me</span>

<span id="ok">Okay!</span>
```

JS code:

```
$('#check').on('change',function(){
    if(this.checked)
        $("#ok").css("opacity", 1);
    else 
        $("#ok").css("opacity", 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No it is working, but your code is not for those 2 reasons.

1. You misspelled `id` on the DOM tag.
2. You have no event listener. You code is running on window load and doesnt check after that. You need to add a [binding](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) like `change`.

Here the proof : http://jsfiddle.net/4Hf9T/13/

```
$('#check').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
        $("#ok").css("opacity",1);
        }
    else if(!$(this).is(":checked")) // "if" not needed, just showing that you can check if it is not checked.
        {
        $("#ok").css("opacity",0);
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before, and someone posted a detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2204275/1745452

The [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) states that it should be working since the first verion. Perhaps you misspelled the selectors?

Comment: And this should have been a comment, and the linked to question's answer has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @KevinB - so should the other answer, and he has almost 8K rep !