# How to write a javascript tracking code?

Tags: javascript, analytics, tracking

I want to write a simple javascript tracking code that should be able to push parameters to a remote server.

- What should I pay attention when writing this code?
- Is there a difference with the new asynchronous codes around (google analytics style)?
- Can you provide a very basic example code?

Thank you

Comment: Is it really clever to use jQuery on a tracking code? Although I can see most sites do have jquery by default too

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) features. Comes with good documentation and examples.

You can send stuff synchronously or asynchronously, via GET, POST etc. See the linked documentation.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Is it really clever to use jQuery on a tracking code? Although I can see most sites do have jquery by default too.

Comment: @Broxzier "This should be a comment." I am still new to Stackoverflow, so I have to get comfortable with the rules and customs here. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Broxzier I agree with Blasius Secundus. We should be more welcoming to new members of our community.

Comment: @HerrK, Blasius Secundus: I didn't mean offense. At first it was only the first line which is a bit too short for an answer.

Comment: @Broxzier still you are the one with more experience, you should know. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users

Comment: @HerrK As I said, I didn't mean offense. If you check my history you can see for yourself how many new users I upvoted for useful privileges and welcomed in the comments in their questions. I learned how to use SO [the same way I just told him about comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545258/is-checked-not-working-while-using-jquery-1-7/16545335#comment23764769_16545335).

Comment: OK no offensive intensions either, next time, be a little bit nicer than. thank you

Comment: Just to be clear, I did not take it as an offense. I just wanted to say that I was not intended to abuse the system in any way (e. g. intentionally posting a comment an an answer to get more reputation or so)

Comment: I know this is an old question but I was wanted to say that I don't think using jQuery for a tracking library is a good idea. You are basically adding +100kb payload when you can probably write some ajax functionality in less than 5kb.