# jQuery get checked checkboxes from name[]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkboxes like so:

```
<ul id="searchFilter">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="1"> $200,000 to $299,999</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="3"> $300,000 to $399,999</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="5"> $400,000 to $499,999</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="8"> $500,000+</li>
</ul>
```

How would I alert the price[] to see what is checked? I am very new at jquery :(

Comment: When do you want to alert..? Do you want to alert the name `price[]` or the actual price which is displayed?

Comment: if i select values 1 and 5, I am looking for an alert with 1,5

Comment: So one alert after checking one , and another with both values after clicking both..?

Comment: `$('input[name="price[]"]').filter(":checked").map(function () { return this.value; }).get());` - http://jsfiddle.net/H7mCt/

Comment: @Ian That's a good *answer* :)

Comment: @Ian please post answers as answer so the question won't remain unanswerd forever...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you can get the checkboxes by `name`:

```
var checkboxes = $('input[name="price[]"]');
```

Then, to get the values of the `checked` ones, you can filter by the pseudo selector `:checked`, and then collect their `value`s:

```
checkboxes.filter(":checked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get()
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Fn9WV/

---

**References:**

- `jQuery().filter()` - http://api.jquery.com/filter/
- `jQuery().map()` - http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:-

```
var selected = [];
$('[name="price[]"]:checked').each(function(checkbox) {
selected.push(checkbox);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector `$('#searchFilter [name="price[]"]:checked')` with jquery to find all the checked checkboxes with the name "price[]" in this form. This will be zero or more elements, depending on how many are checked.

Then use the jquery each() function to iterate over the found checkbox elements, and collect their values into the "checked" array. In the callback function to each(), the `this` points to the current element's dom node, wrap it with `$(this)` to create a jquery object and use `.val()` to retrieve the value from it.

Finally merge the items into a string, to form a comma separated list using the join() function of the "checked" array. It can be an empty string if none of the checkboxes are checked.

```
var checked = [];

$('#searchFilter [name="price[]"]:checked').each (function (i, e)
{
    checked.push ($(this).val ());
});

alert (checked.join (','));
```

Notice that other answers used `this.value` to retrieve the "value" attribute of the checkbox instead of using `$(this).val()`, which is the jquery way to do it and less error prone.

Comment: I'm currently reviewing this answer, as it was flagged for quality assessment by a moderator-level user. Thanks for your answer, your time is appreciated. However, this is considered a low quality answer because it's lacking text explaining how and why it solves the OP's problem. I won't flag this for deletion this time, because it may solve the problem and we wouldn't want to loose it, but it would be good if you could flesh the answer out a little with a few lines explaining how it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
var alert="";
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
  if($(this).attr("checked") == 1)) alert += $(this).val();
  if(alert.length > 1) alert(alert);
});
```

Comment: This will work only for a single checkbox. It won't alert the values of the other checkboxes that might be selected too.

Comment: this only gets me 1 value, I am looking for a list of values, if i select 1 and 5, I am looking for an alert with 1,5

Comment: That's gonna send separate alerts. Need to concat vals in loop and alert after.

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to set each checkbox to a specific id. Then you could use `$('#' + id).is(":checked")` to see if the checkbox is checked. If the checkbox is checked, you could get the range and store it in a variable. You can then return that variable.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery) page if you need some help with the checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

```
//get val on click    
$(document).on('click', ".cb_price", function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                 alert($(this).val());
            }
        });

//a button to call the function
$(document).on('click', ".some_button", function () {
            function getitems();
        });

function getitems(){
$(".cb_price").each(function () {
                //
                var $chk = $(this);
                if ($chk.is(':checked')) {
                    checkboxes = checkboxes + $(this).val() + ","
                }    
            });
alert(checkboxes);
}
```