# How to build an array containing checkbox column status in a datatable?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I have all the required values contained in the fields of the table for further use as they were retrieved by a query. I am trying to make an array of boolean values representing the state of all the check boxes. The state should be determined through `<span class="">` and `<span class="checked">` in my current implementation.

Please help, I have seen many implementations on the web but none address specifically to my predicament, also I am quiet new at this.

Comment: You want to use jquery to get the current state of all checkboxes in a column?

Comment: @markpsmith mainly yes.

Comment: something like this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: I think you should provide a code example and/or a jsfiddle, to have any chance for a constructive answer.