# find checkbox from html through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i don't have much knowledge of the jquery

i have some problem with the Checkbox attribute.

here below i mentioned some code

```
code : $( this ).html()
```

output :

```
<input name="cb_kot[]" class="cb_kot cb_1" id="cb_1" checked="checked" type="checkbox"><label class="quan_count" style="text-align: left;width: 20px; margin: 1px 0 0 0; padding: 0px 20px 0 18px;">1</label><label style="margin-left:18px;width: 170px;">Fish Shorma</label> <label class="bill_price" style=" float: right;margin-right: 20px;">Rs 195</label><a class="icon-x-alt kot_delete" title="Delete" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

in the code i am getting the above html. now you can see in above that there is a checkbox in html. now i want to check that this checkbox is checked or not
so can anyone advice me how can i find it ?

thanks in advance

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

like `$("#cb_1:checked")` in jquery

Refer this link for more details [**:checked**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
$('#cb_1').is(":checked")
```

This code returns true if checked else returns false.

[see more about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var isChecked=$("#cb_1").is(":checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : find checkbox with `id="cb_1"` and check if it is checked or not using `is(':checked')`

```
  var checkedStatus =  $(code).find('#cb_1').is(':checked');
  alert(checkedStatus);
```