# Check if checkbox checked property is not empty using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I check checkboxes checked property? If any of them is not checked, display this sentence in span: "you shoud select one of them". My validation don't work.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="chk[]" />male
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="chk[]" />female
</label>

<script>
    if ($('input[name="chk[]"]:checked').length < 0) {
        $("#textspan").html('you shoud select one of them');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Change `< 0` to `=== 0`

Comment: I don't think a length can be less than `0`, and why are you using checkboxes instead of `radio` input elements for this (mutually-exclusive) choice?

Comment: This question/answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

As far as your specific question goes, when no checkbox is checked `$('input[name="chk[]"]:checked').length` is 0, not negative - so you should change the condition from `if ($('input[name="chk[]"]:checked').length < 0)` to `if ($('input[name="chk[]"]:checked').length == 0)`

[**Full example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fpg41wdr/)

Other than that, some side notes:
1. I'd use radio buttons (as it is more suitable for your current male / female selection).
2. You have the same ID (`chk[]`) twice, which renders your HTML invalid.
3. The [] characters in the ID are not permitted in HTML 4.1 standards, and do not suit the convention.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of changing the code a bit, as your HTML is a bit strange.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/a4jzvoou/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class='gender' id="male">male</input>
    <input type="checkbox" class='gender' id="female">female</input>
</div>
<button class="validate">Validate</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('.validate').click(function(event) {     
     var checkedCount = ($('input[class="gender"]:checked').length))        
  })   
});
```