# How to get list status of checkbox in java?

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox

I have a list checkbox. in jsp page.(JAVA)

```
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="foo" id="${tes.status}" value="${tes.No}"></td>
```

example (checked, null, checked, null). When I use:

```
String[] listStatus = request.getParameterValues("foo");
```

I just get a array is (checked, checked).
How can I get all status of checkbox to String[] listStatus.
Expected: (checked, null, checked, null)

Comment: Do you really need to give an HTML element an `id` in this way? `ids` are not available on the server as you seem to have assumed :).

Answer (score 0):

Those whose list you do not get is unchecked . You can also use jquery to find out

see the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)