# Check if all checkboxes are checked on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have this:

```
<fieldset id="booom">
<label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="a" VALUE="a">something></label>
<label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="b" VALUE="b">something></label>
<label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="c" VALUE="c">something></label>
</fieldset>

<input type="button" id="answer" value="submit">
```

How can I check with jQuery if all checkboxes from fieldset 'booom' are unchecked on submit?

So:

```
if (all checkboxes from parent 'booom' are unchecked) {
alert("something")
}
```

I found many posts about this but none with an actual simple working sample with a button and an alert box :)

Thanks!

Comment: This looks a lot like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `:checked` modifier in a selector.

```
if ($("#boom :checkbox:checked").length == 0) {
    alert("You have to check at least one box");
}
```