# jquery checkbox onchange variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to isolate a variable `n` that is appended to end of a series of input checkboxes. ID=SubDocRecChk0, ID=SubDocRecChk1, ID=SubDocRecChk2, etc.
I want to return the `n` of the checkbox id that is clicked. 
But when I run this code it always returns n as 5, no matter which one I check.

```
  for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {

        $("#SubDocRecChk" + n).on("click", function () {

            if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {

                alert(n + " is checked");
            }
            else {
                alert(n + " is unchecked");
            }

        });
    }
enter code here
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Other resources I've checked but haven't found my specific case. Thanks.

[How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property)

[Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: There is no reason to loop with ids. Use a common class!

Comment: To solve a similiar problem I Always am used to:

 $("input[id^='SubDocRecChk']").on("click", function () {

                var n = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring('SubDocRecChk'.length));

                if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {

                    alert(n + " is checked");
                }
                else {
                    alert(n + " is unchecked");
                }

            });

Comment: thanks gaemaf. This is a concise, creative solution to the issue.