# How to extract content from checkbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a function like this to extract a few data from a form:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#btnEnviar').click(function() {
            var email = $('#email').val();
```

It's working, but now I also need to extract the content of a list box, which is a mark sign.

So I put the list box inside a span with id "idaevolta":

```
      <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;"></ul>
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;"></ul>

 <input id="cbIdaVolta" type="hidden" name="cbIdaVolta" />
```

So far so good, but when I try to extract the data:

```
var idaevolta = $("#idaevolta").html();
```

It is simply not working.

UPDATE

WHILE LOOKING AT THE HTML OUPUT, WITH CHROME CONSOLE, LOOK WHAT I FOUND:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbIdaVolta" name="cbIdaVolta" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; margin-left: 10px;">
```

Does it make things easier to find a solution?

UDPATE 2

It is actually a check box.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the ID "idaevolta" ... the span and the input elements.  ID attributes must be unique.

Comment: Ok, who else is going to say the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can never set two different items with the same id. Only the first one will be recognized. Second, I would use some jquery to say 'if 1st ul is clicked, set #idaevolta value to something'. After this, you'd retrieve the value just like you've done with the email field.

https://api.jquery.com/click/

I hope that helps!

PS: having 'ul's without any 'li' in it just look weird... maybe you should try something different

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused here. I'm using 2 IDs for a hidden input and a span in a different part of the script and they are working just fine, why would this one be different? The form needs to be sent somehow.

Comment: 'working fine' is something accidental. Surely the code is only getting one of the elements. Now that you changed your approach to a checkbox, things will get prettier :)

Comment: I believe this topic will solve your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

1. you can only have one ID in the document, even if they are different elements
2. since you break that rule, you can `$('span').html()`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a unique name for `id`, otherwise use `class`. `ul` element should have `li`. And if you want to get the data from a list. Try something like this:

```
var x = $('#idaevolta').find('ul li').text();
```