# How to check if checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script where checkbox behave like radio button:

```
$(".chb").each(function () {
    $(this).change(function () {
        $(".chb").prop('checked',false);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

I have this loop in view:

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.Banners)
   {
    <tr>
    <td style="border-right:1px solid white;border-bottom:1px solid white;padding:5px;">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PayIn.CheckedPayIn, new   {id="payin", @class = "chb" })</td>

   </tr>
   }
```

How can i check in jquery if and which one is checked?
I tried this but no success:

```
if ($(this).prop("checked") == false)
    {
        alert("false");
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write an on `change` event

```
$('.chb').on('change',function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked'))
       {
           //do something
       }
       else
       {
           //do something
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this. No need to use $.each() while you registering the event.

```
$('.chb').on('change',function(){
      $(".chb").prop('checked',false);
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

But In this scenario, **radio button** is much recommended than check box.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options, like with jQuery `$(this).prop('checked')` or `$(this).is(':checked')`, with pure js `this.checked`, in all given snippets, it evaulate to `true/false`.

```js
$(function() {
  var chbs = $('input.chb'); // cache all
  chbs.on('change', function(e){
    chbs.prop('checked', false); //un-check all
    this.checked = true; //check the current
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='chb' type='checked' />
<input class='chb' type='checked' />
<input class='chb' type='checked' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this

```
if ($(this).val() == false)
{
    alert("false");
}
```

OR

```
if ($(this).attr("checked") == "false")
{
    alert("false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#c1").on("change", function() {

    if ($("#c1").is(":checked")) {
      alert("checked");
    } else {
      alert("not checked");
    }

  })

})
try this,
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" />
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simplify your code by skipping your for loop and allowing jQuery to do the work for you:

```
$(".chb").click(function(){
    $(".chb").prop('checked', false);  // uncheck all
    $(this).prop('checked', true);    // check this one you want
});
```

Comment: he wants to check if checkbox is checked or not, and this is not an answer