# Jquery get value of the current selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the  following radio buttons :

```
<label>Referred to Health Facility</label>
    <input required name="Health_Ref" type="radio" class="wellness_center radiostyle Health_Ref" id="Health_Ref" value="Yes">
    <div class="radiolabel">Yes</div>
    <input name="Health_Ref" type="radio" required class="wellness_center radiostyle Health_Ref" id="Health_Ref" value="No" checked="checked">
    <div class="radiolabel">No</div>
```

And below is my jquery function to get the  values :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".Health_Ref").click(function () {
            var value = $(".Health_Ref").val();
            alert(value);
        });
    });
```

The value being returned when i click the first or second button is for the  first button which is Yes , how is the best way to implement the  jquery function so that I can get the  value of the  clicked radio button ?

Comment: You must try with :checked property. Try the solution given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate question:  Best answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try adding `:checked` to your jquery selector.  [Documentation for :checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

### Option 1 with `:checked`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Health_Ref").click(function () {
        var value = $(".Health_Ref:checked").val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

### Option 2 with `$(this)`

I made the code simpler.  `this` is the value of the element in an event handler, so you can simply use `$(this)` to turn the element into a jQuery object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Health_Ref").click(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Code Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKgBGN

Answer (score 0):

var value = $(".Health_Ref:checked").val();

This selects only the currently checked radio button.

the same works for checkboxes.