# What is the correct way to listen to checkboxes being checked/unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm using this code, to check if checkbox is checked and if it is, show submenu and specific layer on the map:

```
$('input').on('change', function () {
  var x = $( 'input:checked' ).val(); // x gets the value attribute of changed checkbox
  if ($('input').is(':checked')) {
    sublayers.getSubLayer(x).show(); // shows specified layer on the map
    $('#' + x).show(); // shows id targeted submenu under the checked checkbox
  } else {
    sublayers.getSubLayer(x).hide(); // hides sublayer on the map if unchecked
    $('#' + x).hide();  // hides specific submenu
  }
});
```

So what happens is that the first checkbox works right, and following checkboxes do not respond. More to it, if I start checking checkboxes from the bottom to the top they work but show sublayer that fits one checkbox above. Also uncheck doesn't trigger anything.

Comment: Please include HTML and the demo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: You should reference the changed input using `this` inside the event handler. `$( 'input:checked' )` and `$('input').is(':checked')` are just reselecting things from the DOM and may not actually be the input that was changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this` to get the context of the clicked checkbox in your code.

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function (){
            var x = this.value; // x gets the value attribute of changed checkbox
            if (this.checked){
                sublayers.getSubLayer(x).show(); // shows specified layer on the map
                $('#' + x).show(); // shows id targeted submenu under the checked checkbox
            }
            else {
                sublayers.getSubLayer(x).hide(); // hides sublayer on the map if unchecked
                $('#' + x).hide();  // hides specific submenu
            }
    });
```

Here `this.checked` will return `true` if checked else `false`.

Comment: This will work well, but note that there is still another issue that could affect the OP...this will no longer work right if any other non-checkbox input elements are added to the page. This could be averted by changing the selector to 'input:checkbox'.

Comment: @MattBrowne Though i have changed the selector but i dont think this will no longer work right if any other non-checkbox input elements are added to the page.

Comment: It depends on the values of the elements added, but in any case the code in the else block would run unnecessarily.

Comment: nice job on use of non-jQuery properties - would be better still if the identical two selectors inside the branches were refactored outside of the branches.  I suggest `val sel = subLayers.getSubLayer(x).add('#' + x)` then the branches just become `sel.show()` and `sel.hide()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$('input')`

```
$('input').on('change', function (){
    var x = $(this).val(); // x gets the value attribute of changed checkbox

    if ( $( this ).is(':checked')){
        sublayers.getSubLayer(x).show(); // shows specified layer on the map
        $('#' + x).show(); // shows id targeted submenu under the checked checkbox
    }
    else {
        sublayers.getSubLayer(x).hide(); // hides sublayer on the map if unchecked
        $('#' + x).hide();  // hides specific submenu
    }
});
```

Comment: @AtheistP3ace, thanks for your edit. But `var x = $('input:checked').val();` is correct.` because the x does not want unchecked element's value.

Comment: The value of the checkbox determines what he is showing so it must be the value of the changed checkbox. `$( 'input:checked' )` just finds all checked checkboxes. He clearly uses the value of `x` to select an element which is directly connected the the currently changed element, not just checked checkboxes.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace  Thanks that was the problem

Comment: @AlfredUC he does want the unchecked value as well because later he checks if its checked or not and then hides/shows something based on that. Your code is wrong.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace, I have just reviewed it again, then I figured out that your modification is correct. Thank you for pointing out my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` instead of `'input:checked'`

In callback, context is set to element which triggered event. So when `change` event happens and callback is called, in `this` is stored the element. You can than easily determine whether new state of checkbox is checked or not using `$(this).is(":checked")`

Comment: no, use `this.checked`, not `$(this).is(':checked')` !