# Using javascript/jquery, how to validate if at least 1 checkbox in spring's form:checkboxes is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, checkbox

I am using spring's tag in my html. My jsp has a group of checkbox which renders value from model object "allTimeslots". This object has list of string.

```
    form:checkboxes element="li" path="timeslotId" id="checkbox" type="checkbox"
                                            items="${allTimeslots}" /></td></tr></table>
```

Now, my requirement is to check if atleast one check-box is checked when the form is submitted. I am using jquery validation where this check has to be done.
I cannot use type="checkbox" as this is not permitted in spring's tag.
Please suggest.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery

Comment: Found a solution.
$('input[name="timeslotId"]:checked').length >0....
This works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <form:checkboxes element="li" path="timeslotId"
    items="${allTimeslots}" />
```

and in javascript

```
$('input[name="timeslotId"]:checked').length > 0
```

will do the work.