# Why jQuery throwing undefined for checkbox checked property ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-parsing

Following code works inside the onchange property of checkbox:

```
 onchange="if(this.checked)$('#row_date').show();else $('#row_date').hide();"
```

but jquery

```
alert($('#apply_range').checked) // throw undefined, either checked or unchecked
```

not working.

Comment: `alert($('#apply_range').get(0).checked)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: I recommend you don't use inline JS event attributes. Instead use an event listener or jQuery's on method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`checked` is a property of the DOMElement, not a jQuery object. To get that property from the jQuery object, use `prop()`:

```
console.log($('#apply_range').prop('checked'));
```

Or you can access the DOMElement in the jQuery object directly like this:

```
console.log($('#apply_range')[0].checked);

// or

console.log($('#apply_range').get(0).checked);
```

Comment: Isn't this possible for jQuery to fallback to DOMElement property if property is requested, just curious

Comment: Possible, yes. But it would be a massive breaking change, and possibly lead to a lot of confusion. By specifically having to use `prop('propName')` or `get(0).propName` your intent of getting the property value is explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either use `$('#apply_range').is(":checked")` or directly access DOM element: `$('#apply_range')[0].checked`.