# $(this) in place of input

Tags: jquery, input, this

I apologize for the simplicity of this question but for some reason I can't figure out for the life of me how to implement using `$(this)` in place of `$("input:checked")` when looping through inputs to validate a form. If `$(this)`is an input how do I concatenate `:checked`?

What I'm looking to do is start an if statement regarding the current iteration of input's `checked` value so rather than:

```
if ($("input:checked").val() === undefined) {
    //do something
}
```

something like this (but the below isn't working obviously, hence my question):

```
if ($(this) + (":checked").val() === undefined) {
    //do something
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2204250/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

e.g.

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    //do something
}
```