# How to check if input check or not with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I have this switcher (Checked):**

```
<div class="switch try">
<label><input checked="" type="checkbox" class="checkit"><span class="lever switch-col-green"></span></label>
</div>
```

How to know if this one is checked or unchecked when a user click on it ?

**Here what i tried:**

```
$(document).on('click','.try',function(e){
                        if($(".checkit").is(':checked')) {
                            alert("checked");
                        } else {
                            alert("Not checked");
                        }
});
```

But i don't get it working !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: You should most likely attach the `change` event to the checkbox instead, and use a label, not a div.

Comment: If you're trying to show an alert when you click the checkbox container use `$('.try').on('click', ...)` instead of `$(document).on('click', '.try', ...)`. But also be aware that if you click the checkbox, the `click` event will be propagated from the checkbox to the div element.

Could you also add some explanation about what are you trying to achieve with that code?

Comment: @adeneo i solved the problem by changing click event to change event, many thank's.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
$(".checkit:checked").length > 0;
```

or

```
$(".checkit").is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your html from checked="" -> checked

```
<input checked type="checkbox" class="checkit">
```

Jquery is correct as is

Comment: Nothing changed, each time i get Checked.

Comment: `$( ".checkit" ).click(function() {
  if($(".checkit").is(':checked')) {
    alert("checked");
  } else {
    alert("Not checked");
  }
});`   @JisMaxi