# Do different actions based on checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying is quite simple, but for some reason I can't get it working:

I need a way to do different actions based on checkbox state. If it's checked, do something. If not, do something else. For some reason I can only have "checked" state:

```
$('#checkbox1').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#checkbox1:checked')) {
        console.log('do something')
    } else {
        console.log('do something else')
    }
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZROGa?editors=1010

what am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: `if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {`

Comment: `if ($(this).is(':checked')) {`   is more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#checkbox1').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked'))  // here $(this) refers to $('#checkbox1') 
  {
     // do some thing
  }
  else
  {
     // do some thing
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#checkbox1').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#checkbox1').is(":checked")) {
    console.log('do something')
  } else {
    console.log('do something else')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
```

Use like this

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#checkbox1').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    console.log('do something')
  } else {
    console.log('do something else')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is :

```
`$('#checkbox1').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#checkbox1').prop('checked')) {
    console.log('do something')
  } else {
    console.log('do something else')
  }
})`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.prop()` jquery function.

```
$('#checkbox1').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#checkbox1').prop( "checked" )) {
    console.log('do something')
  } else {
    console.log('do something else')
  }
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#checkbox1').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    console.log('do something')
  } else {
    console.log('do something else')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" type="checkbox"><label for="checkbox1">some checkbox</label>
```

Try above one. 'this' keyword points to the current html element.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$('#checkbox1').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#checkbox1:checked').length) {
    console.log('do something')
  } else {
    console.log('do something else')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I like taking this clean approach

```
var check = $("#checkbox1:checked").length;

if(check) //Do Something.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('#checkbox1').on('click', function() {
 if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
  console.log('do something')
 } else {
  console.log('do something else')
 }
})
```