# How to check for a checkbox to be checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 checkboxes. I need one, not both, but at least **1 to be checked**. It is not a multiple selection but zero is not accepted. If one is checked, this line will work `jQuery('#wiz_menu.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');` otherwise it should alert. The following makes it alerting all the time.

**UPDATE**

I am not using the **submit button** or I would have used the [validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). It is a normal button to go next in the wizard `<button type="button" class="btnNext">Next step</button>`

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="usp-category-8" class="usp-checkbox usp-cat usp-cat-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="usp-category[]" id="usp-category-8" value="8" data-required="true" class="usp-input usp-input-category"> 
        Cultura
    </label>
    <label for="usp-category-7" class="usp-checkbox usp-cat usp-cat-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="usp-category[]" id="usp-category-7" value="7" data-required="true" class="usp-input usp-input-category"> 
        Scienze
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="usp-category-required" value="1">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('.btnNext').on("click", function(){
  if(jQuery(".tab-pane").is("#step1")) {
    var isChecked = false;
    $('input[type=checkbox]').on("change", function () {
      isChecked = true;
    });
    if ( isChecked ) {
      jQuery('#wiz_menu.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    } else {
      alert( 'Please, check at least one checkbox!' );
    }  
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2204250/80836

Comment: Setting to true on change will set it to true even when unchecking. But if it's not working at all, try using click (the logic will still be wrong though).

Comment: Why can't you just make them radio buttons?

Comment: @JJJ why should I?

Comment: Because the behavior you're now implementing with checkboxes is the default behavior of radio buttons.

Comment: @JJJ ok thanks, I have accept an answer as it is correct, however I have posted my own answer too for the solution I have adopted in my case which takes your suggestion in consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can use [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('input[name="hi"]').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="hi" value="hi">Hallo<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="gb" value="gb">Tschuss<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Adapted to your code:

```js
$('.btnNext').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#usp-category-7').is(':checked') || $('#usp-category-8').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('at least one is checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="usp-category-8" class="usp-checkbox usp-cat usp-cat-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="usp-category[]" id="usp-category-8" value="8" data-required="true" class="usp-input usp-input-category"> 
        Cultura
    </label>
    <label for="usp-category-7" class="usp-checkbox usp-cat usp-cat-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="usp-category[]" id="usp-category-7" value="7" data-required="true" class="usp-input usp-input-category"> 
        Scienze
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="usp-category-required" value="1">
    <button class="btnNext">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not a submit button i have, otherwise I would have used the validate plugin, it is a normal button to go next n the wizard

Comment: It's meant to be an example of how to use `is` @RobertoMarras.

Comment: ok thanks, I accept this as it is correct, however I have posted my own answer too for the solution I have adopted in my case.

Comment: Check the updated answer @RobertoMarras, I've added an example with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a comment, I personally resolved it like this, making them radio buttons. But I will accept the other answer as it is correct.

```
jQuery('.btnNext').on("click", function(){
  if(jQuery(".tab-pane").is("#step1")) {
   if($('input[type=radio').is(':checked')) {
      jQuery('#wiz_menu.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    } else {
      alert( 'Please, check at least one checkbox!' );
    }  
  }
});
```