# How to know if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to test if a checkbox is checked or no I found this solution but I'm getting nothing

```js
if(document.getElementById('checkbox-1').checked) {
  alert("checked");
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-1" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: there isn't really any 'event' to trigger that JavaScript. Maybe that should happen when the checkbox is checked or not? on 'change' maybe?

Comment: The OP doesn't actually ask for event capturing, just how to test the checked state

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 those are jQuery answers now native JS

Comment: @SamJones the question has the jquery tag in it hence the suggestion.

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 ah yeah, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger click even of check-box which will call a function that do the desired task.

Example how you can do it:-

```js
function checkClick(){
  if(document.getElementById('checkbox-1').checked) {
    alert("checked");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" onclick="checkClick()"> <!-- trigger click event using onclick and calling a function -->
```

Note:- you can change function name according to your wish.

Comment: In the modern era, we should not be encouraging the use of inline event handlers. Also, this question is a duplicate of many, many others.

Comment: It depends how the Inline event handlers are being used. For learning it's ok to use this code. Also, in this question OP said that it didn't work. That means the OP is asking about why the alert didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Trigger the event. For checkbox, the `onchange` event would fire anytime the value changes. So, you need to hook up a event handler which can be a function reference or function declaration like `onchange="checkboxChanged()`

```js
function checkboxChanged(){
if(document.getElementById('checkbox-1').checked) {
    alert('checked');
  }
    else{
      alert('Not checked');
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" onchange="checkboxChanged()"/>
```