# jquery validate check at least one checkbox with dynamicly id's

Tags: jquery

I want to validate that atleast one checkbox is selected. The checkboxes are added dynamicly so the exact ID's are unknown. All i know is that they start with the same ID name e.g.  "Sameid_xxx", "Sameid_xx1"
,"Sameid_xx2" etc..

here is what i have:

```
$cbx_group = $('input[Id^="Sameid"]'); 

$cbx_group.prop('required', true);
if ($cbx_group.is(":checked")) {
  $cbx_group.prop('required', false);
}
```

the problem here is that this makes all checkboxes required. I also dont have form validator

Comment: Assign them the same class and then you have an `each` loop over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$cbx_group.is(":checked")` like below:-

The below code will do two things:-

1.remove `required` from all check-boxes if any-one is checked.

2.Add `required` again back to all check-boxes when all check-boxes are un-checked.

Code:-

```js
$cbx_group = $('input[Id^="Sameid"]'); 
$cbx_group.prop('required', true);
$cbx_group.on('click',function(){
  if($cbx_group.is(":checked")) {
    $cbx_group.prop('required', false);
  }else{
    $cbx_group.prop('required', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="Sameid_XXX">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Sameid_XX1">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Sameid_XX2">3<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Sameid_XX3">4<br>
```

Reference taken:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39849541/4248328

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of checkboxes checked using length

```
 if($cbx_group.is(":checked").length > 0))
 {
    $cbx_group.prop('required', false);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Use `attribute contains selector`. 
Link: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

```js
function test() {
$cbx_group = $('input[Id*="Sameid"]');

$cbx_group.prop('required', true);
if ($cbx_group.is(":checked")) {
  $cbx_group.prop('required', false);
  console.log('checked');
} else {
console.log('not checked');
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="Sameid1">
<input type="checkbox" id="Sameid2">

<button id="one" onclick="test()">Click</button>
```