# how to check the checkbox value is true or not ? I need jquery for this

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are three check boxes . i want to get response as true when corresponding checkbox will be checked and false if unchecked .

```
<div class="">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkboxm1 stream_id1" />
    <label for="indeterminate-checkboxm1" class="black-text">B.Tech/B.E.</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkboxm2 stream_id2" />
    <label for="indeterminate-checkboxm2" class="black-text">Diploma</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkboxm3 stream_id3" />
    <label for="indeterminate-checkboxm3" class="black-text">B.Sc</label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: `$("#indeterminate-checkboxm2 stream_id2":checked")` or `$("#indeterminate-checkboxm2 stream_id2").is(":checked")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate a click event on checkbox and check if it is checked or not like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Here is the link to [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/EKXudpWQ0SJxwxsUdQLM?p=preview) for your work around

Answer (score 0):

> [**Here is the working fiddle for your code.**](https://jsfiddle.net/0nm8qoz3/1/)
>
> There should be a unique id for each checkbox. So, either it'll be `indeterminate-checkboxm1` or `stream_id1`, but you **can't use both of them at a time**.
>
> So, your html will be -

```
<div class="">
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkboxm1" />
            <label for="indeterminate-checkboxm1" class="black-text">B.Tech/B.E.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkboxm2" />
            <label for="indeterminate-checkboxm2" class="black-text">Diploma</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkboxm3" />
            <label for="indeterminate-checkboxm3" class="black-text">B.Sc</label>
        </p>
    </div>
```

> And the generic Jquery code will be like this -

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    $(this).is(':checked') ? alert('checked ' + id) : alert('unchecked ' + id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
if($(this).prop('checked')){
console.log('true');
}
else{
console.log('false');
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
                    <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkboxm1 stream_id1"/>
                        <label for="indeterminate-checkboxm1" class="black-text">B.Tech/B.E.</label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkboxm2 stream_id2"/>
 <label for="indeterminate-checkboxm2"
  class="black-text">Diploma</label>
                    </p>
                    <p>
   <input type="checkbox" id="indeterminate-checkboxm3 stream_id3"/>
                        <label for="indeterminate-checkboxm3"
                               class="black-text">B.Sc</label>
                    </p> 
                    </div>
```

Comment: did you check this? @Sibabrat Swain