# jQuery select current element with same id

Tags: jquery

i have N of checkboxes like

```
<input type="checkbox" id="slider" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="slider">
<input type="checkbox" id="slider" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="slider" checked>
```

When i clicking to checkbox - i need to hadle current checked value(true or false) like this

```
var status = $("#slider").prop('checked');
```

But i awlays hadle first id checkbox value

How can i fix this?

Comment: It's invalid to have multiple elements with the same `id`. ID's must be unique.

Comment: id should be unique, so it is not right to use the same id for multiple elements. Better choice would be to use class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It's invalid to have multiple elements with the same `id`. ID's must be unique. Imagine if everyone's handle was `AskAlexandria`. How would we know who is who?

TIP: If you need to treat a group of elements the same way, use a CSS class name instead.

Most of the time you don't need `id`'s in the first place because they create brittle code that doesn't scale (as you are finding). You can get the checked status of the element that's been interacted with using `this`.

```js
// Instead of grouping several elements with the same ID,
// use classes instead
$("input.choices").on("click", function(event){
  console.log(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="choices" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="choices">
<input type="checkbox" class="choices" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="choices" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

in HTML the ID must be unique and you can't define the same ID for each element,

**for real example: Like The National ID everybody has National ID, but Everybody has a different National ID**

So instead of the ID you can use the classes, and it will work fine,

> HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="slider" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="slider">
<input type="checkbox" class="slider" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="slider" checked>
```

> Javascript - Jquery

```
var status = $(".slider").prop('checked');
```

Hope my answer is useful and helpful !

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes as a way to find groups of elements, as another poster suggested. I personally don't like to do that because I think classes should be for CSS styling, and using them with the intent of making them selectors can sometimes lead to unanticipated consequences if you decide to put some class on another element.

It's perfectly alright to add your own properties to an HTML tag and use those. Unlike `id`, they don't need to have unique values. A way I might handle this would be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="slider0" role="slider" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="slider1" role="slider">
<input type="checkbox" id="slider2" role="slider" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="slider3" role="slider" checked>
```

Here I've added a made-up property called `role`. If I want to find out which sliders are checked, I can get an array of all the sliders and loop through them like this:

```
let checkedSliders = [];
$('[role="slider"]').each((idx,element)=>{
  if ($(element).prop('checked')) checkedSliders.push(element);
}
```

You can use any HTML property *other than `id`* for non-unique values. The point of `id` is that it is intended to be totally unique on the page. Many new browsers will have a console warning if multiple tags have the same `id`.