# MVC Form Data Validation and jquery validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using MVC Data Validation for TextBoxFor and DropDownListFor and its working nice. But I also wanted to add jquery validation for checkbox list is there a way to add that as well? In my document.ready
function I call ready validate(); which add the validator.addMethod but it is not firing.

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4 float-right">Save</button>


 $(document).ready(function () {
validate();
}

var validate = function () {
            $.validator.addMethod("sources", function (value, elem, param) {
                if ($("[name='chkProduct']:checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }, "You must select at least one!");
```

Comment: A checkbox only has on or off, how do you select more than one?

Comment: Sorry is a checkbox list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: By default, the plugin makes at least one checkbox required when the `required` rule is properly applied to a `checkbox` group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using your checkbox as follows:

```
<fieldset id="checkArray">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Apples" />

<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Bananas" />
</fieldset>
```

And then validate via Jquery like this:

```
var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('#checkArray:checkbox:checked').length > 0;
//there should be no space between identifier and selector

// or, without the container:

var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('input[name="chk[]"]:checked').length > 0;
```

Then you can use **atLeastOneIsChecked** to verify if there are any checked boxes or not ( true or false ) and do wathever you want.

Comment: Trying to figure out why this is needed.  The plugin already does the exact same thing when the `required` rule is applied to a `checkbox` group.